# Key hash for Facebook Android SDK

Tags: java, android, keystore, keytool

I can't figure out how to get the Key Hash required to use the Facebook Android SDK. I figured out that I can use `keytool` with these commands:

```
  keytool -exportcert -alias [alias]
 -keystore [keystore] | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl enc -a -e
```

The only problem is that I have no idea where to insert this, I tried through command windows (win7) and I tried opening the file keytool.exe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Download and install OpenSSL from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html based on windows 32 or 64 bit.(Note: Download and install first visual C++ 208 redisributable from that site also )
2. Put the bin directory of installed OpenSSL in windows path.
3. Open the command prompt and go to C:\Users{User_Name}.android
4. now put this command on cmd "**keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64**".(refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#samples)
5. Now enter password "facebook" without double quote.
6. Now a hash key will be generated 
   [image]
7. Finally go to the Facebook Developer site. Make sure you are logged into Facebook and, using the dropdown menu in the top-right, go to your 'Developer Settings':
8. Once you're in your developer settings, select 'Sample App' from the navigation on the left, and add and save your key hash into your profile:
   [image]

Comment: I have generated the key hash but don't know where to put that key, would you guide me? I'm running android studio on Ubuntu.

Comment: Go to facebook Developer site and follow what i wrote

Comment: use password "android" (without quotes) for debug hash.

Answer (score 27):

You can install Open SSL from [here](http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/) , that should make your command work

Comment: For others: It is way more simpler if you keep the keytool and OpenSSL files in the same folder.

Comment: yes, just copy the content of the openssl archive in your jdk1.x.0 folder

Comment: +1 Its working. I am now able to run the command with Openssl.

Comment: I have generated the key hash but don't know where to put that key, would you guide me?

Answer (score 20):

I created a batch script **facebookkeydebug.bat**, which return desired Facebook key hash. Just edit the script, set correct paths, keystore name and run it.

```
:: Getting Android key hash for Facebook app on Windows
:: Requirement: OpenSSL for Windows (http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list)
:: Usage: set paths and run facebookkeydebug.bat

@echo Exporting keystore cert
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\myusername\.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android > debug.keystore.bin

@echo Converting to sha1
C:\PROGRAMS\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl sha1 -binary debug.keystore.bin > debug.keystore.sha1

@echo Converting to base64
C:\PROGRAMS\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl base64 -in debug.keystore.sha1 -out debug.keystore.base64

@echo Done, Android hash key for Facebook app is:
C:\PROGRAMS\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl base64 -in debug.keystore.sha1
@pause
```

EDIT: I published a repo with some batch scripts for signing and getting cert keys on Windows: https://github.com/petrnohejl/Android-Scripts

Comment: I have generated the key hash but don't know where to put that key, would you guide me?

Answer (score 15):

you can use code below to get the Hash key :

```
try {

   PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

   for (Signature signature : info.signatures) 
   {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
    Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
   }

  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
   Log.e("name not found", e.toString());
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
   Log.e("no such an algorithm", e.toString());
  }
```

Reference :

http://limbaniandroid.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-get-hash-key-for-integarte.html

Comment: This one differs from the key generated by keytool code with password "android". Why?

Comment: I have generated the key hash but don't know where to put that key, would you guide me?

Answer (score 9):

To make things easier -

```
keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore -v
```

this should provide you with the fingerprints needed, without the hassle of installing openssl.

e.g.

```
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  1A:5E:AA:CB:1A:CF:68:F0:8B:DA:D8:BC:EE:4F:BF:EE
         SHA1: D2:89:D1:5A:BC:F8:E3:E5:62:4D:DD:20:DD:96:CD:AB:51:A1:C1:7F
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3
```

Comment: but here we needed is Key hash not fingerprints.

Comment: I have generated the key hash but don't know where to put that key, would you guide me?

Answer (score 3):

#### This is an example of how to get the Key Hash from the Keystore:

first we need to get the paths of:

**Java path:**
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\jre\bin

**Open SSL Path:**
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin

(install from: http://www.openssl.org/)

**Keystore Path:**
C:\Data\ANDROID\KEYSTORE\

2) then go to Command line and type:

> cd [Java path]

3) then type :

> keytool.exe -exportcert -alias [alias name] -keystore [Keystore
>   Path]\debug.keystore | [Open SSL Path]\openssl sha1 -binary | [Open
>   SSL Path]\bin\openssl base64

4) the password of your Keystore must be required and then you have the `Hash Key` related to your Android Keystore.

[image]

#### This is the doc of how to set the `Key Hash` for `Facebook`:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash

Comment: I have generated the key hash but don't know where to put that key, would you guide me? I'm running android studio on Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi @Apurva here is the document https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash , i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open a command prompt window. Go to start->run and type 'cmd' and hit enter. Then you have to navigate to the folder where `keytool` is (unless it's in your path), and then type that command.

That is, assuming that command is for windows and not linux.

Comment: Allright! I did a stupid mistake, I navigated one folder from where the keytool was. So, I got a lot of jibberish in return and didn't get the opportunity to enter the openssl. Is this also a program I have installed?

Comment: Keytool I think is installed with the java jdk. I'm not sure if it's in your path though, I don't work on windows. Also, I'm not sure if openssl is installed by default either. Again, that MIGHT be the linux instructions. Are you sure that's the only thing the document says? It doesn't say what you need to have installed, etc

Comment: I navigated myself to the keytool file, and the first command worked. But, when using the openssl i got an error stating that the program couldn't be found. The instructions are here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/README.md under "single sign-on"

Comment: Yeah openssl ISNT installed by default on Windows, facebook sdk tutorial doesn't mention this

Comment: I have generated the key hash but don't know where to put that key, would you guide me? I'm running android studio on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is to generate Key-Hash using code:

```
 public static void generateKeyHash(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.example.user2.testapp",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
}
```

call this method once and generate key-hash, enjoy

Comment: I have generated the key hash but don't know where to put that key, would you guide me? I'm running android studio on Ubuntu.

Comment: first let me know for what purpose you have generated key hash?

Comment: I want to provide `Login using Facebook` support in my app and now I have figured out that I need to put that key to facebook developers site. :)

Comment: okk, go to https://developers.facebook.com/ and register app first then generate keyhash using above code and then paste keyhash

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin\keytool.exe -exportcert -alias "typeYouraliasname" -keystore locationof your keystore | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl base64

Comment: I have generated the key hash but don't know where to put that key, would you guide me? I'm running android studio on Ubuntu.