# Android Key Hash

Tags: android

Hi friends i wanna to generate Key hash to incorporate FaceBook Application in my Apps.. I am having Open SSL Zip. pl guide me how to generate key..

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? A hash of friends in facebook or an intent to launch facebook from your app?

Comment: I wanna to implement Single Sign On in my apps..

Comment: I am getting this error     Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Answer (score 44):

Type this in your terminal (mac)

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Or this into the console (windows)

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

You will have to enter a password.  The password is: *android*

A code will come up and that code is your key hash.

Comment: This works and it is really simple solution. It takes 2 minutes to implement, 100% recommended!

Comment: For me this is solution :)

Answer (score 24):

In order to generate key hash you need to follow some easy steps.

1. Download Openssl from: http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list
2. Make a openssl folder in C drive
3. Extract Zip files into openssl folder
4. Copy the File debug.keystore from .android folder in my case (C:\Users\SYSTEM.android) and paste into JDK bin Folder in my case (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin)
5. Open command prompt and give the path of JDK Bin folder in my case (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin).
6. Copy the code and hit enter

   ```
   keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore > c:\openssl\bin\debug.txt
   ```
7. Now you need to enter password, Password = android.
8. See in openssl Bin folder you will get a file with the name of debug.txt
9. Now either you can restart command prompt or work with existing command prompt
10. comes to C drive and give the path of openssl Bin folder
11. copy the following code and paste 
    openssl sha1 -binary debug.txt > debug_sha.txt
12. you will get debug_sha.txt in openssl bin folder

Comment: i am getting the debug.txt as UUS10U
Android10UAndroid Debug0‚0*†H†÷
 ‚ 0‚
‚ °_»‡IÏy%sT³hN—]q¥¤¤{‰‚¾@TìÐàqÍœ¨éÑ”a 0.†@½ÀrVÓ¢>½ðùäëÀ{9‹0z¥iç‡+åsâI”

and debug_sha.txt as ~hJ1Ðš¡+eK—§¹7 
what could be wrong?

Comment: And i am also getting this `å‡×¤Ä¿{ÑŸC
kêÈƒÚÄ

Comment: I am getting this error,    Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Comment: My answer should be a comment here. Try `openssl enc -a -e < debug_sha.txt` after the final step

Comment: Please follow my another link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash/12405323

Comment: I am Getting Error like in file "keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: debug.keystore";

Answer (score 7):

You only need to do this if you want single sign-on. Here's the details though: [Key hash for Facebook Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347924/key-hash-for-facebook-android-sdk)

Answer (score 5):

1. Download and install OpenSSL from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html based on windows 32 or 64 bit.(Note: Download and install first visual C++ 208 redisributable from that site also )
2. Put the bin directory of installed OpenSSL in windows path.
3. Open the command prompt and go to C:\Users{User_Name}.android
4. now put this command on cmd "**keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64**".(refer https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/)
5. Now enter password "facebook" without double quote.
6. Now a hash key will be generated 
   [image]
7. Finally go to the Facebook Developer site. Make sure you are logged into Facebook and, using the dropdown menu in the top-right, go to your 'Developer Settings':
8. Once you're in your developer settings, select 'Sample App' from the navigation on the left, and add and save your key hash into your profile:
   [image]

Comment: I am getting   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

Comment: Check your java classpath in environment variables

Comment: From where can I check this environmental variables

Comment: I hope u are on Windows. Go to Computer Properties, Advanced System setting then environment varibales

Comment: JAVA_HOME  is  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45    and ANT_HOME is E:\apache-ant-1.7.1-bin\apache-ant-1.7.1

Comment: U may find a environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS there. Just delete that.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Vizzz's answer if you want to get the actual key run in openssl bin folder

```
openssl enc -a -e < debug_sha.txt
```

I guess the detailed steps are for "debugging" purposes

Comment: I'm sure the answer by Vizzz is incomplete without this extra information. This appears to have given me what I needed.

Comment: Although I am glad I helped, I have to admit that I found this information in another site that I don't remember right now and I can't find it either.

Answer (score 1):

paste this code in onCreate() method.

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("your package name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: `info.signatures` is deprecated and the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

by mistake I just figured out a really simple way to figure out what your key hash is. While setting up a new computer I forgot to generate a keyhash before running the FriendPickerSample from the facebook  SDK and I got a message when the sample app opened up on my phone it said. keyhash XXXXXXXX has not been setup by apps developer. From there you can just add the keyhash you see in the XXX to your list and your ready to go.

Comment: I think the asker wants to programmatically generate the hash.

Answer (score 0):

I got issues to get Hash key Then I used following steps and win Hash key of android.

1. Download Openssl from: http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list
2. Make a openssl folder in C drive
3. Extract Zip files into openssl folder
4. Copy the File debug.keystore from .android folder in my case
   (C:\Users\SYSTEM.android) and paste into JDK bin Folder in my case (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin)
5. Open command prompt and give the path of JDK Bin folder in my case (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_05\bin).
6. Copy the code and hit enter
7. keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore >
   c:\openssl\bin\debug.txt
   Now you need to enter password, Password = android.
8. See in openssl Bin folder you will get a file with the name of debug.txt
9. Now either you can restart command prompt or work with existing command prompt
10. comes to C drive and give the path of openssl Bin folder
11. copy the following code and paste openssl sha1 -binary debug.txt > debug_sha.txt

OR (If Getting Error in file like: "keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: debug.keystore" )

12. Enter full code : keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore > c:\openssl\bin\debug.txt | openssl enc -a -e < debug_sha.txt
13. you will get debug_sha.txt in openssl bin folder and  also get a key in CMD.