# Generating hash key for app using facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, openssl, single-sign-on, keytool

I am using facebook sdk for login into my application.
The application runs fine on HTC devices.
The application also works fine on Samsung devices if there is no facebook app pre installed.

But if there is already facebook app on mobile and then the user installs my app, the user is never logged in.
From what I know, I think this might be a problem of single sign on, and I think this is somewhat related with generating proper application hash key, and using the hash key in facebook application which I used to log into the mobile app.

Please guide me how to create the hash key. I am running ubuntu 10.4.

When I run this command in terminal :-

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <your keystore alias name>.keystore -keystore ~/.android/<your keystore name>.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I am never prompted for password, though I am given the hash key.

Comment: [Here][1] you can get your answer, it also helped me.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12405323/2331725


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12405323/2331725

Comment: To generate hashkey[Simple Method is here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash/12405323#12405323

Comment: I have generated the key hash but don't know where to put that key, would you guide me? I'm running android studio on Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you find the mistake? Exactly which command helped you?I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 62):

Try this:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I hope you will get it. I just checked it and I got the prompt for password.

Answer (score 46):

You can use this code block to generate hash key. Put this code block in your onCreate() method.

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "Your package name", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("Your Tag", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me...did also try below command to get the same result:

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Comment: this is it. remember to change "Your package name" with your package name ;)

Comment: Does this code produce same hash key in both: debug and release?

Comment: I have generated the key hash but don't know where to put that key, would you guide me? I'm running android studio on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

If it's not prompting you for password, then first open your terminal and type :

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

And then follow the regular way, just type:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

For password put: `android`
You are all done.

This answer is for debug purpose only, for release purpose use your .jks file to generate hash key.

Comment: Worked like a charm !!

Comment: Thank you, just made the switch to Ubuntu and been trying to fix this for a couple of hours.

Answer (score 3):

Just give the command as:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore
```

and give the keystroke password or android or enter

Here you have to go to the directory structure until ".android" then run this commnad.In general the path is `C:\Users\User-name\.android>`.

Comment: I have generated the key hash but don't know where to put that key, would you guide me? I'm running android studio on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Check three parts in your environment.

1. where is **"debug.keystore"**?

   find `/ -name "debug.keystore"`

   if you can't find it, check you eclipse or ADT.
2. what is **alias name**?

   `keytool -list -v -keystore "PATH_TO_DEBUG_KEYSTORE"`
3. Check if installed **openssl**

   `openssl`

If everything is ready, it should prompt for password

Comment: I have generated the key hash but don't know where to put that key, would you guide me? I'm running android studio on Ubuntu.

Comment: after entering the password for release apk showing chines language please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\openssl\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias aliasName -keystore "C:\Users\s\.android\debu
g.keystore" | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl" b
ase64
Enter keystore password:  android
GEYtOJobR4NzuxX4iOl/yR6sla4=
```