# How to Login to facebook using facebook-sdk for android, After application released

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

an apology, actually I speak Spanish, and my English is very basic, I'm using Google translator, I hope you understand me.

I have an application that connects to the Facebook sdk, I've created my key hash using the example of Facebook, also I created a hash key using my keystore signed by the apk, and also I have that gives you using the Log.

The problem is when I run the application with the device connected to my pc, it gives me login to facebook without problems, but when I export the. Apk to test it on another device does not open the connection to facebook, just do not start session, I hope you can help me.

Comment: Check the key with which you are exporting the apk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have to generate *release* key for facebook and add it on Facebook App developer console for that apps

Follow Below Steps:

1. Download openssl-for-windows from [here](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip&can=2&q=)
2. Now Open command propmpt(admin recommanded) provide jdk path .

   **C:\Windows\system32>cd "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\bin"**
3. Use below command for generating key hash. *You need path to release keystore and openssl bin.*

   **keytool -exportcert -alias "enter alias name" -keystore "D:\mysapp.keystore" | "E:\Projects\facebook-android-sdk-3.6\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "E:\Projects\facebook-android-sdk-3.6\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl" base64**
4. Enter release keystore password.
5. Enter Generated key in facebook app console.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14957365/909497) way for generating your key. If it is not work ,  try to generate your Facebook key by using your release key not your debug key. Hope this helps.