# Can i put the same package name and keyhashes in multiple facebook app?

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to develop a facebook app.I put the facebook login code but i am not abl eto get the facebook login dialog.I get error like cannot find com.facebook.katana.buttonid provider. I have the same package names and keyhashes in multiple apps. Can this create a problem in logging?

Comment: http://amalbit.blogspot.in/

Comment: i get the same hashkey for all the packages. Is it correct?

Comment: I mean i get the same hashkey for com.example.task package and the same hashkey for com.example.myapp.

Comment: Hashkey will remain the same for a given app. use this answer to generate the [hashkey](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14957365/2219600).

Answer (score 0):

you will use the same `Key Hash` for all the Facebook Apps, But your Android apps that use that Facebook apps must be signed with the same `Keystore` what you use to create the `Key Hash`.