# {Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:1xxxxxxxxxxx}

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I want to implement Facebook Login in my application, but here I am getting problem while trying to login i.e :

```
**{Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}**
```

and sometimes this one also:

```
  **{Session state:CLOSED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}**
```

Note: The above problem occurs when my device already has installed NATIVE FACEBOOK APP, if I uninstall the Facebook app it works absolutely fine. Can Anyone please help me out what the matter is ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post in some code.

Comment: Have you figured out how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 12):

Be sure to override in your Activity the onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

Comment: That was my problem, i lost to add this code in onResume of my activity. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Try

`AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken();`

instead of using the toString() function.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old ticket, but no one has appeared to give the correct answer. The token is removed from toString to prevent token exposure.

com.facebook.LoggingBehavior (from line 29):

```
/**
 * Indicates that access tokens should be logged as part of the request logging; normally they are not.
 */
INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS,
```

com.facebook.AccessToken (from line 322):

```
private String tokenToString() {
    if (this.token == null) {
        return "null";
    } else if (Settings.isLoggingBehaviorEnabled(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS)) {
        return this.token;
    } else {
        return "ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED";
    }
}
```

To show the token in toString requests simply add logging to the settings :

```
    Settings.addLoggingBehavior( LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS );
    this.mUiLifecycleHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper( this, this.mCallback );
    this.mUiLifecycleHelper.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
```

Hope this helps others with the same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue for Access_Token_Removed, after i put above 3 lines for what u say. But i get this Error : com.facebook.FacebookException: Unable to create Intent; this likely means the Facebook app is not installed. How to post picture on FB without FB app is installed on device?. I'm using latest SDK3.20.

Comment: Do you have the Facebook application installed on the device? I would need to know what other code you have implemented to give a more concise answer.

Comment: Here get full code http://www.paste.org/76322, No. I need to post image on both cases.

Comment: You need the native Facebook application installed for the SDK service calls to work.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what you come say. Please explain clearly.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand that, what you come to say. Please explain clearly

Comment: Open Google play > Searcg for Facebook > Install Facebook

Answer (score 2):

Just a heads up. 
This exact case was happening to me. My login stopped working just because I changed my `Activity` launch mode in Manifest.xml file from:

android:launchMode="singleInstance"

to

android:launchMode="singleTask"

So, I changed it again to `singleInstance` and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe happening because you didn't add the `hashkey` in your Facebook app. Check out this link [Generating Hashkey for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989237/generating-hash-key-for-app-using-facebook-sdk) to learn how to generate `hashkey`.

This was happening to me too. It started working after i added the `hashkey` in Facebook app.

Comment: The `hashkey` for running directly from Eclipse and by running APK will be different. Which one are you trying?

Comment: I am running the app on my device, one thing more I would like to add is I have tried the APP_ID of Scrumptions Sample too, that too is not working

Comment: As OP said that "The above problem occurs when my device already has installed NATIVE FACEBOOK APP, if I uninstall the Facebook app it works absolutely fine.". I believe that now there should not be issue in the hashkey

Comment: Are `Single Sign On` and `Deep Linking` turned on in your Facebook app?Also the app should be not be in sandbox mode.

Comment: @Apoorv I have made single On and Deep Linking On, No progress yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is my working integration of new Facebook SDK 4.1.
 First you need to init SDKin 4.1 ///

```
/** if face book SDK is not initialized then initialized.*/ 
    if(!FacebookSdk.isInitialized())
           FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(BaseActivity.this);
```

Now you need callback manger

```
/** create face book callback factory.*/ 
    if(null == callbackManager)
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

These are call back.

```
    public final  FacebookCallback<LoginResult> _mcallbackLogin =    new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            if(loginResult.getAccessToken() != null){
                Log.i("TAG", "LoginButton FacebookCallback onSuccess token : "+ loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
              GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                        if(null != object){
                            Log.e("TAG", object.optString("name"),object.optString("first_name"),object.optString("email"),false).execute();
                        }
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.e("TAG", "LoginButton FacebookCallback onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Log.e("TAG","Exception:: "+exception.getStackTrace());
        }
    };
```

Now you need register call back on facebook login button

```
    loginBtn.registerCallback(BaseActivity.callbackManager,_mcallbackLogin);
```