# How can I generate signed hash key for Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, hash, signed

I want to generate **signed hash key.** Before signed my APK I have used debug key store for testing purpose and its Facebook share is working fine.

Now I have signed my application with signed keystore. How can I generate signed hash key through **cmd**?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989237/generating-hash-key-for-app-using-facebook-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with FB doc:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started?locale=es_LA#release-key-hash

It's the same way to generate the debug key hash, but now you have to use the release key store.

Good Luck!

Comment: If the keystore file doesn't have .keystore extension no need to give. If you are give it haven't ask for keystore password.