# facebook integration is not working when the mobile have already facebook application android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, android-facebook

In my application i want to integrate the facebook. I wrote all the code for this.But whenever i click the facebook login button it showing one popup like "Invalid key hash and the key hash XXX does not match with any stored key hash"
If my mobile not having facebook application, then it is working. If my mobile  is having facebook app the facebook integration is not possible to me.

for hash key: (oncreate)

```
 try {
            Log.v("TAG_PACKNAME",""+"UUUU");
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "Your package name",
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.v("TAG_PACKNAME",""+ Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));  // not printing

            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```

i got hash key and release key too. i added both developement key and release key in facebook console. But whenever i click the facebook login button it pop ups like "invalid hash key. the hash key not matched with already stored hashkey"
 please any one help me out.

Comment: Your key hash is wrong.

Comment: @ turtle, how i get key hash in android studio? i am usinng windows os

Comment: from one week i am trying this. But till now i didnt get anytng

Comment: whatever keyhash it is showing when you try to login just add that in your application's facebook developer console and add "=" in it or use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989237/generating-hash-key-for-app-using-facebook-sdk) link to get how to get keyhash programmatically

Comment: @kunu . toByteArray showing error to me

Comment: Are you getting hashkey programmatically?

Comment: this line   md.update(signature.toByteArray());//  toByteArray showing error to me.(cant resolved the symbol toByteArray)

Comment: If my mobile not having facebook application, then it is working. If my mobile  is having facebook app the facebook integration is not possible to me.

Comment: Check you are importing `android.content.pm.Signature` or not

Comment: @kunu,  
If my mobile not having facebook application, then it is working. If my mobile is having facebook app the facebook integration is not working and pop up this error

Comment: That's because of hashkey mismatch. When you have facebook application it is looking for hashkey otherwise it is directing to the web browser.

Comment: ho k. please provide me how i get release key.  (now i am trying for hash key with your code)

Comment: just export your apk and run it again and you will find released keyhash in your logcat.

Comment: @kunu.. once see my edited post. hash key is not coming programatically

Comment: Are you giving your package name? And print your error in catch block.

Comment: main package name or the package name which the activity contain na?

Comment: package name declared in your manifest

Comment: @kunu thankyou i got hash key. now tell me  how i get release key. export the apk means? ( i m new to android)

Comment: Follow [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file) or [http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: it means after i get the apk from android studio i need to run the appliation again. at that time i get release key. am i ryt?

Comment: @kunu after i enter the hash key in facebook, now the error is "this app has no android key hashes  configured"

Comment: Where are you using the hash key? You need to use that in facebook console not in your native application.

Comment: ha yes @kuna i gave this in facebook console only

Comment: @kunu after export the apk and run the app also i got same hash key

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message showing in your mobile when you are trying to login?

Comment: @kunu programatically i got the hash key  i.e   after export the apk and run i got another hash key 0Txxxu=.   in fb console in dev hash key i gave cWXXXXDU=. and for release key i gave 0Txxxu=

Comment: but after i click the login button  again same error like "invalid key hash. The key hash cWXXXXDU= does not match any stored hash key. The hash key i got and what the pop up hash key also same

Comment: yes store both hash key in your console.

Comment: @kunu i saved both keys. but it showing same error

Comment: Okay so you are telling that lets `XYZ=` hashkey is stored in your dev console and while you are trying to login it showing `XYZ= does not match any stored hash key`

Comment: @kunu...yes...exactly..the both hash keys are same

Comment: @kuna any suggestions for this issue?