# How do I generate a key hash for the Facebook SDK On Mac?

Tags: android, facebook, macos, key

I'm trying to obtain the **key hash** for integrating facebook into my Android app.  But all over the net I can't find the way to do it on `MAC OS X`, only for `Windows`.

If someone could light me with the proper way to obtain the key hash I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score -28, accepted):

Sorry, what key tool?

If you want to generate a Facebook App ID/Key, go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps and create a Facebook app.

If you want the keytool that you can use to create certificates etc, that is included in the jre.

Explanation for how to deal with the keys and hash here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

Comment: yeah, thanks :) I figured that out too and edited the post :)

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.I was trying to say that I need the signature of my app so I can integrate facebook in it!The keytool is integrated in jre but I don't know how to use it to generate my app signature for FB!

Comment: I'd daresay they're for Mac only. You have to change them a bit for it to work on Windows, but since you're on Mac you should be fine.

Comment: I'm new to MAC so pls lgiht me a bit:I have to use my terminal and locate my android sdk and at its location execute those commands:D.I know that what I'm asking is foulish but I really don't manage:D.Thank u!

Comment: Yes. You have to use the terminal. If you got specific questions regarding that, that should probably not be on SO since they're not programming questions per se. At least they should be separate questions. Feel free to mark your question as answered and post new questions regarding how to use the terminal on Mac OS X (but probably not on stackoverflow). Good luck!

Answer (score 185):

I used following steps to generate a Key Hash for my app in facebook: (I am using **Mac OSX 10.8**)

1. First open a terminal (open a command prompt in windows).
2. Navigate in the terminal to the directory where your Android **debug.keystore** is stored.
3. Mostly it will located under “/Users/user_name/.android/” (In Windows will be C:\Documents and Settings\.android).
4. Once you are in the “.android” directory, run the following command.

   **keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64**
5. When it prompts you for a password, type **android** and hit Enter
6. Copy the value printed in the terminal that ends with an “=” and
   paste it in the Key Hash field in Facebook. Then click the Save
   Changes button.

Reference: [Integrate Facebook logins in your Android app](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/integrate-facebook-logins-in-your-android-app/296)

Comment: Tip: When compiling a `custom.keystore` mind to change the password to the one that you have given when you created the custom.keystore.

Comment: hello Arun, it has been a while since the answer. I just released an android app and it has the facebook login property. So is the key hash taken in your way is the release key hash or can it only be used in developement mode?

Comment: Saner I m sorry for delayed response. I stopped android development for 5yrs. Unable to reply bac

Comment: I was in my project directory on Terminal & used command: 

**keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64**

When prompted for Keystore password, I mistakenly entered 'q' and pressed enter and my key was generated. lol

Answer (score 26):

Please follow below steps to find *debug.keystore* and generate *key hash* for android development at mac.

1. Open terminal
2. Type **cd ~/.android** and hit enter to go to **.android** directory
3. If you want to open **.android** directory in finder, type **open .** and hit enter. Then **.android** directory will be opened in finder where you can find *debug.keystore*. If you do not want to open *.android* directory and only want to generate key hash, then skip this point and follow *#4*.
4. In terminal where you are already in .android directory type

   **keytool -exportcert -alias alias_name -keystore sample_keystore.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64**

   and hit enter.
5. You are asked for password. Enter **android** as password and hit enter. Then you get key    hash ending with "="
6. Copy key hash,enter in your facebook app setting page and save changes.

Answer (score 8):

Never did it on Mac before, but here are some advices:

1.You need OpenSSL. Install it. In Windows I just extract zip file, then copy three file include openssl.exe in bin folder to jdk's bin folder (where keytool is), don't know how it work on Mac.

2.Copy file keystore what you want to get key hash to jdk's bin folder. My keystore is debug.keystore (because I'm still in test, I don't want to use the main keystore).

3.Using command line to go to jdk's bin folder (In Windows, I just **Run** -> **cmd** -> type **cd %JAVA_HOME%**)

4.Type this command:

**keytool -exportcert -alias alias_name -keystore sample_keystore.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64**

In my case (debug.keystore):

**keytool -exportcert -alias *androiddebugkey* -keystore *debug.keystore* | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64**

then enter password for debug.keystore: **android** (without password, the key hash's still generated and the same as with password, don't know why).

You'll get some string with "=" character at the end. Go to your app setting -> mobile -> fill that key hash (include "=") to Android key hash.

Comment: Linux and Mac store debug.keystore at the same path: ~/.android/debug.keystore. If you want to create new keystore, follow instructions in this link http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: You start your answer with _Never do it on Mac_. The user asked specifically for help on Mac OS. You should at least explain why you think he should never do it on Mac (which is not correct by the way, there are no problems generating the keys on Mac)

Comment: @yacc Sorry for make you misunderstood with my poor English. I mean I never did it on Mac, but I thought the way to generate the keys on Mac is generally the same as on Window, so I gave him the answer.

Comment: @AnhTuan You need to specify the actual location. keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" | C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe base64 and your install instructions are not clear. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash the answer with the highest number of votes to coreect

Answer (score 4):

(honestly, not an answer, just a note for all visitors having this or similar trouble)

There is a way to obtain a key hash without JDK and OpenSSL by using pure Java utility [android-fb-keytool](https://github.com/demitsuri/android-fb-keytool/). You can checkout and build source code.

Comment: Fixed a broken link

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, for generating a key hash, follow the simple steps below.

1. Open Terminal
2. Paste Below Command (Step 3) And Hit Return
3. `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore  | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`
4. Enter Password : Android
5. It will give you Key hash (like MibyjIEJWghOLquRdk9esClXHWH=)
6. This will give you a debug key hash. Also we can generate a Release key hash with the same Process. Just need to change our keystore path and password.

Happy Coding. Thank You