# android facebook login stops working if app is downloaded from google play

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I uploaded my fully working app on Google Play and when download it from there, facebook login doesn't work!! I properly configure my facebook app and works with eclipse environment. After searching, it can be done due to facebook key hashes. However, I obtained it like:

[How to generate Key Hash for facebook SDK In Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661993/how-to-generate-key-hash-for-facebook-sdk-in-mac)

Seems that a key hash for distribution must be also obtained... but how? Thank you.

Comment: That is expected. You generated the Key Hash for the debug key while testing using Eclipse. You will also need to generate a Key Hash for your app using the release key, the one that you signed your app with for deploying on Google Play. Do that, and you will be good to go. ;-)

Comment: @SiddharthLele Perhaps you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Alternative 1:**

Use this with the app *signed with your release key*. **Not** the one that is deployed from Eclipse.

Run this piece of code in the first Activity of your app:

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature: info.signatures)  {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.e("FACEBOOK APP SIGNATURE", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This line: `Log.e("FACEBOOK APP SIGNATURE", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));` will log the Key Hash in DDMS.

**Alternative 2:**

1. Download [OpenSSl for Windows](http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list) and extract the .zip to a simple location like: c:\openssl with all the contents of the zip extracted in this folder's root.
2. Copy your signing key file to your JRE installation's bin folder. For example, in my case: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin`
3. While in the bin folder where you copied the signing key, Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ Right Click -> Open command window here.
4. Run this command: keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_SIGNING_KEY > c:\openssl\bin\debug.txt
5. Enter your password for the signing key
6. Now, navigate to the c:\openssl\bin folder and type in the following commands:

`openssl sha1 -binary debug.txt > debug_sha.txt`

And then,

`openssl base64 -in debug_sha.txt > debug_base64.txt`

Done! The **debug_base64.txt** contains your Key Hash. Copy this in your app console and you are all set.

In my experiece, both the methods have given me the correct Key Hash. However, in a few cases (rather random ones), the first alternative did not give the correct Key Hash while the second alternative has **always worked**. See which works for you.

Comment: for alternative1, it returns me key hash that I already have, debug one!but I need distribution one. I have apk file signed but how to acces to it in order to get key hash?

Comment: @Jaume: Have you exported a new Signed APK with the release key? You will need to do that, then manually copy that APK on your device, install from a File Manager and then run the app with the device connected to the computer and the DDMS view open.

Comment: @Jaume: I suspect it still gives you the old key hash because you haven't exported a signed APK and installed that.

Comment: well I did it with signed apk and it returns a different key hash. This seems to be what I was expecting and then, I added to facebook key hashes on my app. However, still doing the same... Should I modify something else or am I missing anything?

Comment: problem was on log key hash. I don't know why but must be saved first as string and then log it. After that, solved!! many thanks for "alternative 1" code!! really thankfull

Answer (score 1):

While generating release Hash key, Note this

When generating the hash key for production you need to use `openssl-0.9.8e_X64.zip` on windows, you cannot use `openssl-0.9.8k_X64.zip`

The versions produce different hash keys, for some reason 9.8k does not work correctly... 9.8e does.

*OR*

Use this below flow

This is how I solved this problem
Download your APK to your PC in java jdk\bin folder
in my case `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_121\bin`
go to java `jdk\bin` folder and run cmd then
copy the following command in your cmd

`keytool -list -printcert -jarfile yourapkname.apk`

Copy the SHA1 value to your clip board
like this `CD:A1:EA:A3:5C:5C:68:FB:FA:0A:6B:E5:5A:72:64:DD:26:8D:44:84`
and open [Hex To Base 64](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php) to convert your SHA1 value to base64.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, for me I was getting the same error, but working fine now after trying hours.

[Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051517/login-error-there-is-an-error-in-logging-you-into-this-application-please-try/56952547#56952547)