# Android - Google Maps stopped working after publish

Tags: android, google-maps, hash

I was developing my App in Android Studio and it was working fine in debug mode on different devices. Then I wanted to publish it.
So I generated the signed APK and I also had to create the key store.
I made up the key store password, key alias and key password.

In my App I am using google maps. But now it stopped to work. I tried to re-create the API key but it is still not working. I am searching on the web and if I understood well I need to create a new API key using the hash from the keystore.jks? Is this correct? I am a little bit lost. How can I get this hash on a Mac system?

I found this thread:[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6661993/how-to-generate-key-hash-for-facebook-sdk-in-mac)

Where should I use this hash than? Should I use it instead of SHA fingerprint when generating the API key?

Comment: Have you try tihs link : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#restrict-key

Comment: thank you, i found the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found the answer: [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#restrict-key)

I had to to:

```
keytool -list -keystore your_keystore_name
```

Then I entered the password and used the SHA fingerprint provided to generate my Google API key.