# Facebook API login fails with FB app installed on phone

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am building an app, which is going to have support for facebook. I have downloaded facebook API and their sample called "Hackbook" from original Git repos. The problem is with login - if original FB app is not installed on phone, the login is going through custom dialog and everything works, but if FB app is installed, the Hackbook automatically redirect to original FB app, and then nothing happened. It's impossible to login. 
I have tested this on five different phones, and always was the same problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had a similar problem. In my case, I had not created a hash key using my signing key. I just had the one hash key created using the **debug.keystore** default signing key.

As soon as i created a hash key using my app release signing key, that problem was sorted out. If you haven't already done this, create a new hash key using your signing key (for uploading on the market) and add that to your app's facebook control panel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added that hash key into control panel, but problem is still here. Do I have to add hash key also into fb api somewhere?

Comment: @virusss8: You don't need to add the hashkey in your app. Follow this step and tell me the result. Open the Util class file in your facebook-sdk and change the 'private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = false' to 'true'. Now keep your phone connected to your development PC and run the app created using the signed apk and log in. Keep a DDMS window open and see if it generates an error.

Comment: D/Facebook-authorize(25124): Login failed: invalid_key:Android key mismatch. Your key "*********real*key************" does not match the allowed keys specified in your application settings. Check your application settings at http://www.facebook.com/developers

but I have never set that key anywhere. What key is that???

Comment: That's the key you should put in the apps control panel. Copy the key shown in the log and replace the key you last put (using the signing key) with this one from the DDMS log.

Comment: Anytime fella. ;-) Glad I could help.

Comment: @UceMAN I am not able to found private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = false in my FacebookSDK Util class. I am using FacebookSDK 3.0.1. Can you please help me? I want to login my app with intalled Facebook application. And I am using appId which is made by release keystore.

Comment: @anddev: Unfortunately, that does not work with the new SDK. Use the method listed under _Solution 1_ here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13283088/450534. That will do the job.

Comment: @IceMAN I got the hashkey. Thanks. Can you pleas help me in my query? I posted my question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464648/how-to-get-default-facebook-app-login-session-in-to-our-application-in-android It is very greatful if you will give me the solution please help me .

Comment: @SiddharthLele Did you updated your apk on GooglePlay with a new one or just replaced the hashkey in your AppSettings on Facebook? I have just replaced the hashkey on Facebook, wait several minutes, tried again(with the app already published before) and still doesn't work?

Comment: @AlexAndro: No need to update the APK. Just add the new Hash Key and it should be all good. As long as the correct signing key has been used for the app as well as the Hash Key, no need to update the APK. It does take a little time to filter down FB's system. In my experience, I had to wait almost 4 hours before an app of mine started to work properly.

Answer (score 5):

I have toiled for two days & got the solution at last, this is the **WRONG** way to get the hash key -

```
keytool -exportcert -alias *<your _alias_name>* -keystore *<key_store_path>* | [openssl_bin_directory]\openssl sha1 -binary | [openssl_bin_directory]\openssl base64
```

The **right way** is type these 3 lines, one at a time in cmd. After the first line, you'll be asked to insert the keystore password.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias *<your _alias_name>* -keystore *<key_store_path>* > [openssl_bin_directory]\debug.txt
[openssl_bin_directory]\openssl sha1 -binary [openssl_bin_directory]\debug.txt > [openssl_bin_directory]\debug_sha.txt
[openssl_bin_directory]\openssl base64 -in [openssl_bin_directory]\debug_sha.txt > [openssl_bin_directory]\debug_base64.txt
```

If you want to know details, the **RIGHT** way is described here -

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13281913/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-with-release-key-hash

or here

[Facebook Android Generate Key Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash/12405323#12405323)

Comment: Why would you post the wrong in text and not the right? I almost used it lol but thanks for the link to the right one

Comment: THANK YOU just spent the last 3 hours trying to figure this out

Answer (score 1):

Get you hash key using this function for both(debug and release apk) and put it in your app in developer.facebook.com/apps

```
private void calculateHashKey(String yourPackageName) {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                yourPackageName,
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:",
                    Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this help me a lot.. Hope this will help you too..

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue . After getting Key hash by using   `keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`  I have logged in first time in release mode successfully... 
Then second time i got the common error 
Your key `"*********real*key************"` does not match the allowed keys specified in your application settings.

Just use the `"*********real*key************"` which Facebook gives  in error message I logged in successfully now in release mode. 
So be sure while entering this key that you use the exact same key. The LETTERS  I , `small(L) i.e (l)` will make you in trouble. I made two keys , in the first key I've used `small(L) i.e (l)` and in second key I've used I. and placed these keys in developer app.
It is working now ....

Comment: That was the exact problem in my case..the only solution that worked! and the part about small 'L' is correct, and also Big 'I' (which might look like a small 'L' in some fonts..

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that the user-login gets cancelled when the facebook app is installed on the device even after generating right keys.

I added following line before login and it works great.

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that the user-login gets cancelled when the facebook app is installed on the device even after generating right keys in Xamarin Android.

I added following line before login and it works great.

LoginManager.Instance.SetLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.NativeOnly);