# Android Facebook remote_app_id does not match stored id Error

Tags: android, facebook

In my application user have to login via facebook, but i am getting this error,

```
**my logcat error:**

02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988): Exception during service
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988): com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiException: remote_app_id does not match stored id 
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:74)
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:103)
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponse.g(ApiResponse.java:208)
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:267)
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:28)
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.SingleMethodRunner.a(SingleMethodRunner.java:125)
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.c(PlatformOperationHandler.java:274)
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:175)
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue.d(OrcaServiceQueue.java:218)
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue.d(OrcaServiceQueue.java:38)
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue$3.run(OrcaServiceQueue.java:169)
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-14 18:00:01.821: WARN/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue(10988):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
02-14 18:00:01.876: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(10988): Failed to send
02-14 18:00:01.876: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(10988): com.facebook.orca.ops.ServiceException: API_ERROR: API_ERROR
02-14 18:00:01.876: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(10988):     at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation.c(OrcaServiceOperation.java:610)
02-14 18:00:01.876: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(10988):     at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation.c(OrcaServiceOperation.java:40)
02-14 18:00:01.876: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(10988):     at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation$2.run(OrcaServiceOperation.java:575)
02-14 18:00:01.876: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(10988):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-14 18:00:01.876: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(10988):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-14 18:00:01.876: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(10988):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-14 18:00:01.876: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(10988):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
02-14 18:00:01.876: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(10988):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 18:00:01.876: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(10988):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-14 18:00:01.876: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(10988):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
02-14 18:00:01.876: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(10988):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-14 18:00:01.876: WARN/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog(10988):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i'm creating hash key like this,

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\rama\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl" base64
```

i got key then added to facebook setting.

give me some good idea to this,

thanks.

Comment: the reason behind this exception is wrong openssl,please see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16212920/1939564

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the main Activity of your application, in the onCreate(), put this code and run the app.

This will give you the correct Key Hash that is needed by Facebook. Apparently, JRE 1.7 does that occasionally.

Copy the result that will be displayed in the logcat trace and paste in your App's Facebook console and you should be good to go.

```
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "ENTER.YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.e("MY KEY HASH:",
                Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
```

**EDIT:** Almost forgot. **Don't** forget to replace the `ENTER.YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME` with your app's package name. ;-)

**UPDATE:**

**Solution 1:**

Try this link: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1. I found that using the Facebook method of getting a Hash Key did not always work as advertised. This link however, has a different method of getting the Hash Key and has pretty much always worked.

**Solution 2:**

That being said, I always found the simplest thing to do was, *let the Facebook SDK tell you what your Hash Key is*. This is by far more simpler and shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes.

Step 1:
In your Facebook SDK, locate the *Util.java* class. In that, change this:

```
private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = false;
```

to:

```
private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = true;
```

Step 2:
Create a **new** Signed APK, transfer to your device and install. If it is already installed, naturally, it will prompt.

Step 3: With your DDMS (Logcat) running and your device connected to the computer, run the application and keep looking for a *key mismatch* warning. That warning has the **actual** Hash Key. Copy that key, go to your Facebook Developer page and add the new key to the list.

Comment: This one tried already..it will give hash key that one added to facebook setting getting same error.

Comment: @Ramachandran: Hmmm... Ideally, it should have worked. Anyway, try one of the alternate solutions in the edit.

Comment: Util.java  this class not there facebook sdk3.0 and one more In my project first launched activity is splashscreen.java , but user login activity is setting.java which one i want to add to facebook app register package com.myapp.splashscreen or com.myapp.setting.

Comment: @Ramachandran: Then try the method under the title **Solution 1**. That is how I got mine. The second one I discovered a little later. The first one is lengthy, but it will work for sure.

Comment: please tell me this one i am getting confused, In my project first launched activity is splashscreen.java , but user login activity is setting.java which one i want to add to facebook app register package com.myapp.splashscreen or com.myapp.setting.

Comment: @Ramachandran: If you mean this: 
        `<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>`, it just has to be in your Manifest. You don't need to assign an Activity to it.

Comment: no i telling facebook register page --->>>Native Android App          -->Package Name:-->Class Name:--->Key Hashes: this details we need to fill facebook. i am confusing what is Class Name??

Comment: @Ramachandran: That will be the first activity that starts when the app is launched. I have changed my login console too after registering the app on FB and there has been absolutely no side effect. Refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/link-to-your-native-app/#config

Comment: @Amorgos: I am glad it did. :-)

Comment: @Rstar: Which one doesn't work? Have you tried the One under the title _"Solution 1"_? That one has always worked for me. Quite a few others report success using their method too.

Comment: @IceMan yes i've followed the steps even i'm getting correct Key Hash Using PackageInfo but still it iving me this error

Comment: I works only in few devices , on click many devices open dialog facebook dialog and rest of asking like "This app want to access public progile" reply yes or not , How is it possible ?

Comment: @Rstar: I am stumped why this would happen. I have never seen this behavior to know a solution. I have also never seen any of the methods for getting the Hash Key fail. One of the solutions has always worked for me.

Comment: @IceMAN none of the method is working, i have generate Hash key using this tutorial http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1 and i got same hash key which i have received using PackageManager

Comment: Solution 1 works. But is there a way to reuse my already existing keystore from another project?

Comment: @Ron: I am glad the solution was helpful. I am not sure what you mean by your question. But if I understand it correctly, a Key hash can be re-used as along as the signing key (whether the key for deploying on Google Play or the eclipse's debug key) are the same for the app. As far as my experience goes, I have a paid app and free app which uses the Facebook SDK and their Key Hashes for default debug keys are the same. No issues with that. Do correct me if you meant something entirely different though. ;-)

Comment: Solution 2 is the best. I had my application already in Google Play and I didn't need to change anything to fix it. Go for solution 2.