# Error while using Android FB SDK 3.0.1

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to login with FB see next error in the log. Did anyone have same issue before? What could be the issue?

**Log:**

```
06-04 11:32:36.570  15384-17337/?  W/fb4a:fb:OrcaServiceQueue: Exception during service
        com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiException: The app is not authorized because it has preconfigured permissions.
        at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:74)
        at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:103)
        at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.ApiResponse.g(ApiResponse.java:184)
        at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:267)
        at com.facebook.katana.server.protocol.AuthorizeAppMethod.a(AuthorizeAppMethod.java:28)
        at com.facebook.orca.protocol.base.SingleMethodRunner.a(SingleMethodRunner.java:125)
        at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.c(PlatformOperationHandler.java:274)
        at com.facebook.katana.server.handler.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:175)
        at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue.d(OrcaServiceQueue.java:214)
        at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue.d(OrcaServiceQueue.java:37)
        at com.facebook.orca.server.OrcaServiceQueue$3.run(OrcaServiceQueue.java:168)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
06-04 11:32:36.590  15384-15384/?  W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog: Failed to send
        com.facebook.orca.ops.ServiceException: API_ERROR: API_ERROR
        at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation.c(OrcaServiceOperation.java:597)
        at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation.c(OrcaServiceOperation.java:38)
        at com.facebook.orca.ops.OrcaServiceOperation$2.run(OrcaServiceOperation.java:562)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Posible duplicate see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875027/android-facebook-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stored-id-error has also this error. Make sure everything is setup correctly in FB "06-04 11:32:36.590  15384-15384/?  W/fb4a:fb:GDPDialog: Failed to send
        com.facebook.orca.ops.ServiceException: API_ERROR: API_ERROR"

Comment: It's not same error. As well our app is 5 years on the market so it's configured correctly. We are migrating to FB SDK 3.x.

Comment: Hmm I thought you meant the API error. But above in the log it says "The app is not authorized because it has preconfigured permissions." So did you tried to fiddle around with the app permission regarding facebook permission not the manifest I guess. But both worth looking add. You can delete the app in Facebook profile of you're account and try to ask again for permissions. Give that a try. http://www.facebook.com/help/204306713029340/

Comment: This is exactly the case - new user or user that removed app from FB list will stuck with this issue.

Comment: But existing users wont have a problem?

Comment: Unless they don't delete app from FB. But the new users are really important case.

Comment: What kind of facebook permission do you ask in the app, maybe some are deprecated or changed?

Comment: It's not because permissions. We tried to get access token without them.

Answer (score 0):

I know that question is old but I think problem is that you test your application on user that has not permission for this app. I.e. you have test application and production application, and have some test user. So you try to enter test application with test user which hasn't granted access in application roles