# Facebook error : allow key: configure your app key hashes at dev.facebook android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

When i run my facebook apps i get the following error. allow key. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/178779105632639 ...

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: You sure that is the correct link? It just redirects to the FB Developer Home Page...

Comment: yes it is the rerror i get from my apps. look at my updates i post an image

Comment: This is new! Never seen this one before. How have you generated your app's Key Hash?

Comment: yes my keyhash is something like 46:AD:40:...

Comment: Right. But what method did you use to get the Key Hash? By the way, by the looks of it, that doesn't seem to be a valid Key Hash. A Key Hash would look like this, for example: **b95FcVzXo33YLn5ZPyD+B8mBqS0=**. See if this [solution of mine here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14875153/450534) helps get rid of the error.

Comment: i tried your solution 2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk= but the problem of hash key is not solved

Comment: This is really really curious. My Google fu can't find anything even remotely close to this problem. :-( Can you try the Solution 1 in the link?

Comment: i tried solution 1 still same problem

Comment: Did you remove the earlier Key Hash from your app console and put in the new one?

Comment: Try this for fetching the Hash key< http://www.javatechig.com/android/how-to-get-key-hashes-for-android-facebook-app > and Paste the right Hashes Key value in My Apps -> Settings ->Basics(Key Hashes) in developers.facebook.com/apps... sorry for late reply but might help someone cuz i faced same issue...

Answer (score 3):

It seems that hashkey you generated is not correct. You can generate app hash key from the following code. Try it

```
public static void showHashKey(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.example.project", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES); //Your package name here
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.v("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried still key hash inccorect

Comment: Have you installed signed apk or unsigned apk on your device?

Comment: i run it from eclipse

Comment: @Dimitri try doing what section "Create a Development Key Hash" says here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started EDITING (maybe late but hope that helps someone)

Comment: I installed FB apk on my device and I assigned the hash key correctly but I still get the same error, Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

1.It will Help you.Working fine [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27468813/4447803)

2.while creating app, in developer site  using some keyhash generated by your cmd prompt,use that KeyHash copy and paste
in developer Settings Page keyhash Column.

3.change the Single sign on toggle button-YES

Answer (score -1):

You need to generate a hash key for your application and register that to the FB Developers console where you have created the application. I have written a blog for the same. You can find it out at :
 http://www.solutionanalysts.com/blog/android-generate-key-hash-facebook

Hope this helps you.

Comment: its not my oncreate but how can i set permission for publish using btPartager

Comment: Link is useless. As nothing is there