# Android key hashes not configured

Tags: android, facebook

[image: Here is my FB console[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5X35.png)I implemented facebook login as mentioned in this [link](http://www.learn2crack.com/2015/06/android-facebook-sdk-implementation.html). I added my app in facebook's developer page, added hash key and got the app ID. On first run, app was able to log in successfully. But after that, when it comes to the facebook page, it shows error that "This app has no Android key hashes configured. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/. I don't know what the problem is as the hash key is already added in the facebook account.
[image: This is the error showing]

```css
Manifest

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfblogin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider<my app id>"
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:exported="true"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

```html
Main Activity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    Button share,details;
    ShareDialog shareDialog;
    LoginButton login;
    ProfilePictureView profile;
    Dialog details_dialog;
    TextView details_txt;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        login = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        profile = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.picture);
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.share);
        details = (Button)findViewById(R.id.details);
        login.setReadPermissions("public_profile email");
        share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        details_dialog = new Dialog(this);
        details_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_details);
        details_dialog.setTitle("Details");
        details_txt = (TextView)details_dialog.findViewById(R.id.details);
        details.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                details_dialog.show();
            }
        });


        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
            RequestData();
            share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                    share.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    details.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    profile.setProfileId(null);
                }
            }
        });
        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().build();
                shareDialog.show(content);

            }
        });
        login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
                    RequestData();
                    share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            }
        });

    }
    public void RequestData(){
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {

                JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                try {
                    if(json != null){
                        String text = "<b>Name :</b> "+json.getString("name")+"<br><br><b>Email :</b> "+json.getString("email")+"<br><br><b>Profile link :</b> "+json.getString("link");
                        details_txt.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
                        profile.setProfileId(json.getString("id"));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,picture");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

Comment: you key is not sigh key is add in facebook console panel

Comment: @Destro. How to add sign key in facebook website?

Comment: Add you HasKey in you facebook console

Comment: check this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: @JaydipUmaretiya. When I add the hash key it display a diff error as shown in the 2nd pic.

Comment: This is my console http://imgur.com/EZAIb8I

Comment: @SomnathPal... are sure u create haskey as given in facebook console doc.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27469003/646806

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your `Activity` and get key in `HashKey Log`. Add this `HashKey` in you `Facebook` console.

```
public static void showHashKey(Context context) {

// Set Your Package Name                                                                                                                 
String m_PackageName = "com.example";

    try {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(m_PackageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES); 
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("HashKey", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("HashKey", e.getMessage());

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.d("HashKey", e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

Comment: @himani mehta. I tried ur way and added the code in the MainActivity but no hash key was generated. Then I added the key shown in the error screenshot and now its working fine.