# Integrating Facebook login in ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic3, angular5

I am trying to integrate `Facebook` login in an ionic application, after seeing the `ionic` documentation and follow the steps, I have successfully integrated it, but getting this error when run on my `android` device and click on the Facebook button,

```
 Error: this app has no Android key hashes configure.
```

I use the following command to generate a key

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

I got a key, which I inserted in the key hashes field of my Facebook app. But still get this error when click on the Facebook button

```
Invalid key hash. The key has ************ does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/MY_APP_ID
```

This I have already configured. My question is, whether I have to put the app on play store before able to see the functionality of the Facebook button?
If NO, the how can I test this in development mode?

Answer (score 1):

Copy that key and go to developer.facebook.com, where you have registered your app for `facebook` verification and include under key hashes.

```
Please Note that : If the hash key differ, You need to include it freshly.
```

Please refer this link for more details [This app has no Android Key hashes configured. - Login with Facebook SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468813/this-app-has-no-android-key-hashes-configured-login-with-facebook-sdk)

Comment: The key generate by the app was different from that i generated and saved in Facebook. So as i copied the one generated by the app and saved in in Facebook the error was gone. Thanks

Comment: @Anana Aristotle, glad to help you.