# Android Facebook SSO not working

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

In my Android application I integrate Facebook feature with "SSO" feature. My app shows the following exception:

[image: snap from mobile]

I have created "Key Hash" using the following command:

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Fssd1\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64
```

and placed the key hash in facebook app details:
[image: Facebook app creating page]

I did the following:

1. Downloaded the facebook library 3.0.2
2. I run the app directly from eclipse to mobile.
3. I have all necessary permissions to login also "offline".
4. My app is works in emulator not in mobile(Facebook default application is installed in mobile).

I have spend a lot of time to find out the reason but couldn't.

My doubts is why the facebook shows different key with generated key hash from above used command.

Is any problem in creating key hash? if then how to create in wright way?

Why my app is not working with SSO?

Is anything I missed / wrong in my process?

Is anything need to add in AndroidManifest.xml file? such as "SingleInstance".

please assist me to make work my app with SSO.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: did you added the key hash in the Facebook Developer console ?

Comment: @murali_ma: That screenshot you have posted is of the Facebook Developer console. ;-) [This could help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14875153/450534) fix the error.

Comment: yes, But i assumed some think different., Have you findout the problem?

Comment: @murali_ma: Did you added in the Developer Settings too ?

Comment: Make sure you build apk using debug.keystore as you uses the same for generating hashkey.

Answer (score 2):

Create hash key by using this command. Print the hash key to LogCat and copy paste it to Facebook:

```
private void printHashKey()
{
    try
    {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.your.package",
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature: info.signatures)
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("YOUR HASH KEY:",
                Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    }
    catch (NameNotFoundException e)
    {

    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
    {

    }
}
```

Ensure to replace `com.your.package` to your application package.