# app is misconfigured for facebook login on some devices

Tags: android, facebook

**I get this error page:**

> xxxxxx app is misconfigured for facebook login

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWYQy.png

**And this is the configuration I am using:**

[image]

I know this is because of some package name or hash key mismatch. but:

**on a Samsung Galaxy Ace GT-S5830 with 2.3.6, Login works fine. But on a HTC Desire C with 4.0.4 I get the above error message**

similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495127/getting-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-in-some-devices), but no solution.

Comment: try enabling logging as described here and see if there are any clues on the reason of the error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13283088/375929

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest to you to upgrade to latest Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android. Please take a look here: https://developers.facebook.com/android/

And here's the guide to upgrade from 2.x to 3.x: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/androidsdk/3.0/upgrading-from-2.0-to-3.0/

About your problem, sometimes I get it too and seems a random facebook error.