# facebook api for android "session.isOpened();" always return false

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am new to android facebook api I want shear image with tag on my wall but the session is always return false.
I have done all the steps of key hash etc.

```
      // start Facebook Login
      Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

        // callback when session changes state
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            if (session.isOpened()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "da ho tost ka kana", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                publishStory();
                // make request to the /me API
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                  // callback after Graph API response with user object
                  @Override
                  public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                      if (user != null) {
                          publishStory();
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello " + user.getName() + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                          actionBar.setTitle(user.getFirstName());
                        }
                  }
                });
            }
        }
      });
```

And this is on activity result

```
      @Override
      public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }
```

session.isopened(); always return false;

Comment: Can you add a line to your callback's call() method, and return any exceptions that may be passed to it? The most likely cause is that your hashkey is not set correctly (the one you generate on the command line is not always the one that Android generates, especially if you're a Windows machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I remove the Facebook app from device then it work.
In order to work with Facebook app you should create a relese Key. 
consider these links

[Facebook API login fails with FB app installed on phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516401/facebook-api-login-fails-with-fb-app-installed-on-phone)

and

[App is misconfigured for Facebook Login with Release Key Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281913/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-with-release-key-hash)

and

answer two of this question

[Key hash for Android-Facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app)