# misconfigured for facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I have made an application which shows me above message when I have installed facebook sdk 3 in my emulator(but application works as expected after clicking ok) or device but works fine when i Uninstall the facebook sdk . Its even happening with the examples given with facebook sdk (I am just importing them and running) . But works fine without installing the facebook sdk in device or emulator. The message showing is as follow.

```
  power is misconfigured for facebook login.press okay to go back to the application without connecting it to facebook...
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to edit the `app_id` in your `values` to match the Facebook app you're using.

also, you need to add the `key hash` to the app settings in the Facebook developers consol.

Comment: I have followed the tutorial on facebook developer and I have done both things (aap_id would be in value/strings just to confirm)... and another thing is facebook examples should work.........

Comment: is it trying to connect to the same app all the time? (in your case `power`)

Comment: no in my application it is but in the facebook example I am not editing anything.... and both are working fine without facebook sdk 3 installed......

Comment: wait, you're trying to use the 3.0 SDK without installing it and are wondering why it doesn't work?!

Comment: ahh I am saying if facebook is already installed in device or emulator ....  I am adding facebook sdk as library of the application in eclipse

Comment: did you also add the reference to your string id in your app's metadata? Something like

`<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I have toiled for two days & got the solution at last, this is the **WRONG** way to get the hash key -

```
keytool -exportcert -alias *<your _alias_name>* -keystore *<key_store_path>* | [openssl_bin_directory]\openssl sha1 -binary | [openssl_bin_directory]\openssl base64
```

The **RIGHT** way is described here -

http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13281913/app-is-misconfigured-for-facebook-login-with-release-key-hash

or here

[Facebook Android Generate Key Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash/12405323#12405323)