# Android/Facebook: Obtaining hash key

Tags: android, facebook, eclipse, hash, key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Android Generate Key Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash)

I'm trying to obtain a hash key for using facebook with my android application. I downloaded openssl and put it in java\jre7\bin

Here what I type in the console

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
-keystore C:\Users\morgane\.android\debug.keystore ¦ C:\Program Files (x8
6)\Java\jre7\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary ¦ openssl base64
```

I have this error:

> Illegal option:  ª
>   keytool -exportcert [OPTION]...

I don't know what the character  ª means and how to fix my error.

By the way is the key necessary to make fb works with an android app?

Comment: You're going to have to put the `"C:\Program Files (x8
6)\Java\jre7\bin\openssl.exe"` bit in quotes for the shell to accept it. You're in that directory aren't you - why not just `openssl.exe`?

Comment: ... and if you're having trouble with the whole sequence of commands why not try writing the output to disk at each step rather than trying to pipe it all together?

Comment: tried just with openssl instead of the entire address, still have the same error ?

Comment: OK, try doing the parts separately: `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\morgane\.android\debug.keystore > cert.txt` then `openssl.exe sha1 -binary < cert.txt > cert-sha1.bin` and finally `openssl.exe base64 < cert-sha1.bin` to see where the error really is. (You may need to change the intermediate step paths to somewhere writeable if you're not running as an admin user.)

Comment: Yes, I have Access denied for the 1st part. I should change the debug.keystore's path?

Comment: No, the `>cert` part: e.g. `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\morgane\.android\debug.keystore > C:\Users\morgane\.android\cert.txt`,  `openssl.exe sha1 -binary < C:\Users\morgane\.android\cert.txt > C:\Users\morgane\.android\cert-sha1.bin`, `openssl.exe base64 < C:\Users\morgane\.android\cert-sha1.bin`

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be that it's the pipe character which is not recognized by `cmd.exe` and instead passed to `keytool` as an argument, which causes the error from `keytool`. Try typing the pipe character yourself on the keyboard if you copy/pasted it from somewhere.

Comment: No I've written it myself :/