# Android Facebook sample app doesn't login when FB app installed

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

At first I thought this was my app but I get the exact same problem when using any of the FB sample apps.

Take the HelloFacebookSample for example, which gives you a login button and after login shows you your pic and enables you to post status updates.

If I don't have the FB app installed on my phone the login button gives me a web view which i login through and the photo appears in the app and i can make posts. However if the FB app is installed on my phone it brings up a dialog saying the app would like to access you public profile etc. I press OK and..... nothing.

I have found many questions that seem similar but the problem was usually using a debug key as opposed to a release key, but I am running from eclipse so the debug key is still appropriate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if there is the default Facebook App is installed in your phone or if you are trying to upload your app on Google Play, then you need a different KeyHash. because, when u developed your FB app you have registered your FB app with a key hash which is created by using the default debug.keystore.

so, now u need a different KeyStore to generate the different KeyHash. u need a signed KeyStore, which u can get by the help of [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYhJp-jqJyM) , after generating new keystore, generate a key hash and register your FB App with this new key hash. this should work.
for generating new KeyHash u can follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash/12405323#12405323)

Comment: Ahhhh that was it. I used my release keystore. Thanks

Comment: @shoshi I tried using my app keystore file and generate new hash key and application key but still not working for me. I want to login in my application with the installed FB application login. I am always found session.isOpened() = false. Can you please help me I am stuck on this. I didnt found any useful way/article to solve this.

Comment: @shoshi you can see my code here :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464648/how-to-get-default-facebook-app-login-session-in-to-our-application-in-android

Answer (score 1):

I found the next line that helped me in the above scenario:

```
mLoginFacebook.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
```

it comes right after:

```
mLoginFacebook = (LoginButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
mLoginFacebook.setFragment(this);
```

solved all my problems..
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I would try and follow this tutorial to see if you can get a sample app that you build yourself to connect with Facebook.  I had issues connecting the sample apps with Facebook as well.  I would also check that your app id from Facebook is in your manifest file.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/