# Session Login does not react when Facebook app is present. Works with SSO

Tags: android, facebook, single-sign-on

I've implemented Facebook for my android app following this guide:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

My aim is to get the access_token so that i can connect it with my backend server

Current situation:

- Application is fully functional when Facebook app is not installed. Facebook SSO is invoked and all will proceed as per normal
- When Facebook app is installed the native Facebook dialog requesting permissions appears and it subsequently has no more further actions.

[image]

Any Facebook experts care to enlighten regarding the matter?

Comment: see my ans : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036956/android-facebook-sample-app-doesnt-login-when-fb-app-installed/15037770#15037770

Answer (score 2):

Ok I got it solved!

It is as Shoshi has mentioned in his comment.

[Android Facebook sample app doesn't login when FB app installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036956/android-facebook-sample-app-doesnt-login-when-fb-app-installed/15037770#15037770)

The keyhash of the keystore that signed the android app should be added in the Facebook App console.

So in short:

1. Export Signed App
2. Get keyhash from keystore. See [Facebook Android Generate Key Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash/12405323#124053233).
3. Add the hash value to Facebook app

It might take awhile for FB to register the hash value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be  the hash key that you have uploaded and that i got from the code below were different. try this code this code, get the hash code in the console, update it on the facebook console and it would login perfect. I am posting this so that my fellow developer save some time that i have spent in solving this problem.

```
try {
PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
      "com.facebook.samples.loginhowto", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
for (Signature signature : info.signatures){
       MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
       md.update(signature.toByteArray());
       Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
}
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
}
```