# Facebook login missing UI

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

After I login in Facebook the native dialog shows, but when I press OK nothing happens, the app doesn't update the UI when the facebook.apk is installed, but it works fine from WebView login(without facebook.apk).

Any suggestions?

I completed the getting started & how to: use Facebook login tutorials, my code looks like these & manifest its fine.

Comment: Are you requesting any data from Graph API?

Comment: Did you run any of the sample apps (like Scrumptious or Hello Facebook) and see if login works with those? Please post code on how you're using the SDK (and if you're using any of the included buttons/fragments).

Comment: No, is a simple login with publish permissions @Fahad Ishaque

Comment: im using facebook LogginButton & the samples have same problem @Ming Li

Comment: Any erros in the log? That tend to happen when you either havent placed your facebook generated key in your app on their site or when you have a wrong facebook key set in your apk.

Comment: No errors and log is empty, please read my question edited @Gagriel Netto

Answer (score 0):

i have answered this same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036956/android-facebook-sample-app-doesnt-login-when-fb-app-installed/15037770#15037770), and this worked for the guy.

***ANSWER:***

if there is the default Facebook App is installed in your phone or if you are trying to upload your app on Google Play, then you need a different KeyHash. because, when u developed your FB app you have registered your FB app with a key hash which is created by using the default debug.keystore.

so, now u need a different KeyStore to generate the different KeyHash. u need a signed KeyStore, which u can get by the help of [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYhJp-jqJyM) , after generating new keystore, generate a key hash and register your FB App with this new key hash. this should work. for generating new KeyHash u can follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash/12405323#12405323)

Comment: Solved!!, in NBAndroid to export APK, extension .keystore is required when save file, then export the certificate with keytool and ssl, the result is the correct key for Facebook APP. Thanks all for your answers.