# UnknownError: ApiException:Key hash **** does not match... when I have FB app installed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hash

I will note first I am very new to java and android development and possible could have missed something simple.  I working through the Facebook example "sessionlogin."  It works while there is no Facebook app.  When I install the Facebook App and try to run the code it fails with the error

```
UnknownError: ApiException:Key hash BGyx5d0rMOuY9aQqZK4B9q04+no does not match any stored key hashes
```

The first thing that I concluded was the obvious the keys are not match, but why? I am confused as to why the app would work without and what the difference in the hash key is for the FB app? Does it use my app's key? Does the FB app require a signed app to access its data?

As for the some of the things i have done, I added a snippet of code to output the hash key at the start of the app.  In all cases BGyx5d0rMOuY9aQqZK4B9q04+no= was displayed.  The app was stuck in debug mode, so I signed and published the app as explained in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036956/android-facebook-sample-app-doesnt-login-when-fb-app-installed#answer-15037770).  In return the hash that I was using was egNzXZN1fDDeK7PNL+QzHDAKUsg= (on FB, returned from the console cmd ln) but the snippet was returning BW0xQ5kipPoWYWWJd1g3yaKCe6M= when the app actually ran.

After reading through dozens of articles and working through about half of those, I've lost lots of time trying to learn what I am doing wrong and I am now, completely clueless. How can get a working example? Am I missing some fundamental configuration?

Details:

- java 7 release 25
- win 8 64bit
- ADT (eclipse)

Comment: Did you try adding the key from the exception message into your app settings? The exception is generated on the server side, so it's the most accurrate.

Comment: When you mean server side you are referring to the FB app settings? If so I have tried this.

Comment: OK, I guess it's not clear to me from your question which hash keys you've added to your app settings, and which ones you're seeing errors with. I'm assuming that you're using two different key stores, one for debug, and one for a signed APK. What methods did you use to generate the key hashes for each keystore, and what are the errors associated with each when you try to run it (e.g. is your debug app working, but the signed one not working)?

Comment: I generated the hash keys from the command line, and in all cases I added the keys to the Facebook app.  At one point i had added about 6 keys none of which worked for the signed app.

Comment: Are you seeing the "Key hash xxyy does not match" error for your signed app? And if so, can you just add xxyy to your app? The error is supposed to display exactly what Facebook is trying to verify.

Comment: Thank you, I did notices that the two keys are similar and have added both with no success. I am looking to maybe redo everything for the facebook to see if it is a missing step, human error, from my side.

Comment: can you tell me what the solution of this ,I am facing the same problem ,I have 2 keys 1st is I m generated from command prompt and other is getting using 1st ans

Comment: @SAndroidD I was not able to return to this project and hence never resolved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

From the troubleshooting section of [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook#troubleshooting) guide, add this to your onCreate:

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "com.mypackage.name", 
                    PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.e("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                }
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```

Add the keyHash shown as is. It will be very similar to the one in your error log but with / & - replaced

Comment: i will check this out, it will be a little while before I get to it. Thanks