# Facebook Login Error When Facebook App Is Installed On Device

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, android-facebook, android-keystore

I am suffering with Facebook login issue in my android app. If there is no Facebook app installed on android device or I use an emulator, Facebook login works properly. But if Facebook app is installed on Mobile than it gave an error.

**Error in facebook lite app**

[image: Error in Facebook lite]

**Error in facebook app**

[image]

I am using 2 different mobile and both gave same error. I followed this SO question : [Android Facebook sample app doesn't login when FB app installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036956/android-facebook-sample-app-doesnt-login-when-fb-app-installed/#answer-15037770). With this SO Question I understood that this error arise after Generating signed apk in android studio.
So I used signed Keystore (.jks) to generate new Key Hash. After generating new key hash I added this in facebook app>Settings>Basic But Still getting same error in Both mobiles. How can I fix this error. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use **android** as your password, use that password that created during genrating signed apk

Answer (score 1):

You need configure app setting in facebook developer concole and add the generated KeyHash in KeyHash field.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | "PATH FOR openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Password: android
```

Comment: YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH  this is path of keystore but what i need to use here YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS

Comment: Standart location for  debug.keystore is  |~/.android/ on OS X and Linux |
C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\ on Windows XP |
C:\Users\<user>\.android\ on Windows Vista and Windows 7, 8, and 10

Comment: YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS is android

Comment: i used both _android_ and C:\Users\<user>\.android\ but still getting same error

Comment: sorry, try this Keystore name: "debug.keystore"
Keystore password: "android"
Key alias: "androiddebugkey"
Key password: "android"

Comment: I m using password **android** but need to use my own android signed keystore password that I was created when generating signed apk

Comment: If you use your own keystore -  generate for it KeyHash and put it to the facebook app, and your app will be work for both version of apk

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by added to my FacebookHelper

```
LoginManager.getInstance().loginBehavior = LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY
```

now login dialog opens in browser and works correctly

Answer (score 1):

use this

LoginManager.getInstance().setLoginBehavior(LoginBehavior.WEB_ONLY);

when you sign in through your app, Facebook won't allow because there are two Facebook instances(your app and Facebook app),you must enable web only in your app.