# Getting Classcast exception on calling Session.openActiveSession of facebook sdk for android

Tags: android, facebook, session

I am working on a application in which i want to show the friend list of the user and select one of them and show it on my screen. But when i call **Session.openActiveSession** to get the active session because user is not logged in yet it gives me a Exception "Key protocol version expected String but value was Integer". But when i further investigate it on multiple devices it comes on only those devices that doesn't have facebook application installed. So my question is what to do to show a friend list in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Post your code please so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

The `Key protocol version expected String but value was Integer` it is not an error from your part. It is an error from the Facebook SDK itself. I had thought it was an error that wasn't allowing me to log in, but it turns out it is not. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415899/sso-singe-sign-on-not-working-when-facebook-app-is-installed-on-device) link and look at the answer by hakanostrom.