# Facebook Scrumptious login doesn't work.

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to integrate facebook to my android app for login. I couldn't do it because of following error, so I tried the same with one of Facebook samples "Scrumptious". I am getting the following log on my logcat. I am using Facebook Sdk 3.5 and following log is from Scrumptious Sample of Facebook.

```
12-15 12:14:28.800: W/Bundle(20526): Key com.facebook.platform.protocol.PROTOCOL_VERSION expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value <null> was returned.
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1061)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4256)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$KatanaLoginDialogAuthHandler.tryAuthorize(AuthorizationClient.java:821)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryCurrentHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:272)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient.tryNextHandler(AuthorizationClient.java:238)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$GetTokenAuthHandler.getTokenCompleted(AuthorizationClient.java:772)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at com.facebook.AuthorizationClient$GetTokenAuthHandler$1.completed(AuthorizationClient.java:731)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at com.facebook.internal.PlatformServiceClient.callback(PlatformServiceClient.java:144)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at com.facebook.internal.PlatformServiceClient.handleMessage(PlatformServiceClient.java:128)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at com.facebook.internal.PlatformServiceClient$1.handleMessage(PlatformServiceClient.java:54)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4929)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
12-15 12:14:28.810: W/Bundle(20526):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-15 12:17:37.910: D/dalvikvm(20526): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
12-15 12:17:37.990: D/dalvikvm(20526): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3341K, 32% free 9340K/13699K, paused 12ms+4ms, total 73ms
12-15 12:17:37.990: W/CursorWrapperInner(20526): Cursor finalized without prior close()
```

The app asks everytime for permissions, when I push "log in with facebook" button.

Thanks for your helps.
Have a nice sunday

Comment: Checkout this answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415899/sso-singe-sign-on-not-working-when-facebook-app-is-installed-on-device

Comment: Tried all the possible solutions, which have been listed there. Didn't help

Comment: Try updating the version of the SDK you're using. This should be fixed in later versions. The current version is 3.6.

Comment: I tried it too. Having this issue with the Scrumptious example of Facebook Android Sdk 3.6

Comment: @akbas I am facing same issue not with sample but with my own app...have you figured out any solution?