# Android Facebook api 3.7- ApiException:The app must ask for a basic_info permission at install time

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

**I'm using sdk 3.7**
My Android application doen't use FB authentication, but I have a share button.

On this button click, I trying to create a session and open a FB WebDialog, when I do that I'm getting dialog that asks me for publish permission and after that the Session doen't opened and I'm getting `com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException: UnknownError: ApiException:The app must ask for a basic_info permission at install time.`

I tried: 
1. to add 'basic_info' permission.
2. to uninstall my app and the fb app and install again.

**How solve this problem?**
(see my code below)

```
    @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            boolean isFacebookResponse =
                    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (isFacebookResponse) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookShareClick() {
            checkFacebookLogin();
        }

/**
     * Login to FB if needed
     */
    private void checkFacebookLogin() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        try {
            if (session == null || session.getState() != SessionState.OPENED) {
                logInToFacebook();
            } else {
                publishFeedDialog();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * login to facebook
     */
    private void logInToFacebook() {
        String app_id = getString(R.string.app_id);

        Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

        Session session = new Session.Builder(this)
                .setApplicationId(app_id)
                .build();
        session.addCallback(this);
        Session.setActiveSession(session);

        List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");

        // Login
        if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
            session.openForPublish(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                    .setPermissions(PERMISSIONS)
                    .setCallback(this));
        } else {
            Session.openActiveSession(this, true, this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Disconnect from facebook
     */
    public void logOut() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (!session.isClosed()) {
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (state == SessionState.OPENED) {
            publishFeedDialog();
        }

        if(exception !=null){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void publishFeedDialog() {
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "test name");
        params.putString("caption", "test caption");
        params.putString("description", "test description");
        params.putString("link", "test link");
        params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

        WebDialog feedDialog = (
                new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(this,
                        Session.getActiveSession(), params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                        if (error == null) {
                            // When the story is posted, echo the success
                            // and the post Id.
                            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                            if (postId != null) {
                                //DebugToast.show(getApplicationContext(), "Posted story, id: " + postId);
                            } else {
                                // User clicked the Cancel button
                                //DebugToast.show(getApplicationContext(), "Publish cancelled");
                            }
                        } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            // User clicked the "x" button
                            //DebugToast.show(getApplicationContext(), "Publish cancelled");
                        } else {
                            // Generic, ex: network error
                            //DebugToast.show(getApplicationContext(), "Error posting story");
                        }

                        logOut();
                    }
                })
                .build();
        feedDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, I didn't build a project with FB API, not yet but I will try to help you. As far as I can read, you need to `separate the request of read and publish permissions.`

According to the [FB API Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#publishing):

> Apps should separate the request of read and publish permissions. Plan your app around requesting the bare **minimum of read permissions at initial login** and **then any publish permissions** when a person actually needs them.

So, your code might be:

```
/*
 * login to facebook
 */
private void logInToFacebook() {
    //...
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this)
                .setPermissions(Arrays.asList("basic_info"))
                .setCallback(this));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, this);
    }
}

/*
 * set the publish_actions permission here
 */
private void publishFeedDialog() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    // check the session
    if (session != null){
        // create a new permission
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                .NewPermissionsRequest(this, Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
        // set a new publish permission request
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        //...   
    }
}
```

Maybe this answer might help you with this: [SSO (Singe Sign-On) not working when Facebook app is installed on device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18496849/2668136): he does this on the `call` method and he said:

> Since call() gets called anytime there is a change in the Session, the session.isOpen() will be true, if we do not check if the permission is set, we will enter in an infinite loop.

You have [this information](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook#permissions-publish) about `requestNewPublishPermissions` on the docs:

> This method is used to request permissions in addition to what the app has already been granted. This happens **after an initial connection has been made to Facebook**.

I saw this solution on this step: [Add Publishing Logic](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#linkapi-step2) hence you can read:

> The method will first check if the logged-in user has granted your app publish permissions; if they have not, they will be prompted to reauthorize the app and grant the missing permissions.

I hope this will help you.