# Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider

Tags: android, facebook

I want to sign in to my app with Facebook, but I get next message to my Logcat:

```
Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider
```

and launcher does not loading. I get my hash key [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash/13488560#13488560).

My code is:

```
case R.id.btn_start_facebook:
        // callback when session changes state
        // start Facebook Login

        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {

            // callback when session changes state
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {
                if (session.isOpened()) {

                    // make request to the /me API
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                // callback after Graph API response
                                // with user object
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                        Response response) {
                                    if (user != null) {

                                        Log.d("myDebug",
                                                "Hello " + user.getName()
                                                        + " user id = "
                                                        + user.getId()
                                                        + "!");

                                    } else {
                                        Log.d("myDebug", "User is null");

                                    }

                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I had same problem. I logged out from the face book application that was installed on my tablet. After that It was working fine.

Answer (score 10):

add permission of internet in menifest of your application

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: To check the internet connection might help to. My wifi went down, that triggered this error.

Answer (score 5):

The issue for me was that that facebook app installed on Android was outdated and not consistent with my Facebook Android SDK.

Please look at this page: [Developer Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/) and be sure that that the Facebook SDK is consistent with the Facebook app that installed on your Android.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to do more error checking like this

```
if (user != null) {

    Log.d("myDebug",
          "Hello " + user.getName()
          + " user id = "
          + user.getId()
          + "!");
} else {
      Log.d("myDebug", "User is null");

      FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
      if (error != null) {
           Log.d(String.format("Error: %s", error.getErrorMessage())); 
      }
}
```

Comment: no, launcher does not open, i can not enter my email and password

Comment: i have checked it. I have this in my Manifest

Comment: did you give permission for internet access in the manifest? Also where do you set app ID? Like activeSession = new Session.Builder(mainActivity).setApplicationId(appId).build();

Comment: i make next 
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

Comment: Internet permission is enabled

Comment: You have to make sure that add_id in your string resources is valid for the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody has that same error and the answers above did not work check if you move your facebook app to SD card. When you connect your smartphone to the pc it automatically disable every apps located at SD card.

The solution that I found was move the Facebook app to the phone again to test.
You could also disconnect the smartphone and run the application and it works fine, but you will not have access to debug etc.