# SessionLoginSample login problems

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, android-facebook

Currently I'm trying to get the facebook api to work. When I launch SessionLoginSample on my virtual device and hit login via the activity it works just fine. Even though I don't have Faceboook on the device it points me to the website.

When I try to launch login through my actual device (Galaxy S2+) it does nothing. I get a Facebook popup asking me if I want the app to give acces to my profile and friends list. The options under it are cancel and ok. When I hit OK it changes into a loading wheel popup which disappears after a few seconds, but nothing happens. It doesn't log in. Same goes with Scrumptious on my android phone.

I do have Facebook on there.

Edit. When I remove the Facebook app from my phone it does work. What is going on?

Comment: first update Facebook version to latest Facebook version of your device..

Comment: Already done that. Also tried re installing both the app I'm making and facebook.

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed the problem. There were multiple others having the same problem, but nothing actually worked. What do you have to do is this:

1. Export Signed App
2. Get keyhash from keystore. See [Facebook Android Generate Key Hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash/12405323#124053233).
3. Go to your developers settings and put the hash in there.