# getPackageManager() error while trying to obtain Android hash key from Android code

Tags: android

I am trying to get a Android hash key for Facebook for my app using this code in my `Utility.java` class

[image]

but the `getPackageManager()` method is flagged, is it an import problem or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getPackageManager()` is a method of the `Context` class. I'm not completely sure where you have the code above but it seems to be in some sort of a helper class. You need to pass a `Context context` parameter to the method where your have this code defined and then change the line that uses `getPackageManager()` to

```
context.getPackageManager()...
```

Comment: Yes it is in a helper class i created, and your suggestion removed the error although(due to the logic in my code) it didn't work.But i found from [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash?rq=1 that the best way to generate a hash key from android code is to place the code above in the 'onCreate()' method, and run the application.Works like a charm from there. Thanks though.