# Android Facebook login, session is always closed on USB debugging

Tags: android, facebook, session, hash

I'm following the [Scrumptious sample tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/) to implement the Facebook login for my Android app, which contains the code below. When I tested it on the emulator, it worked fine, but when I used the USB debugging, **session.isOpened()** always returned false. I also generated the key hash following [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash).

```
@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoggedMainActivity.class));
    } else {
        showLoginFragment();            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem, and solved by just uninstalling the facebook app on my mobile (which was downloaded from the play store). I don't know the exact reason but it works for me. It also doesn't affect your development process because you can still got all the facebook functionalists through the facebook library.

Comment: Yes, I used the same way.

Comment: I have the same issue but ... Will the application work fine when it be released in the Play Store and operate someone having installed the Facebook app?