# Facebook Integration tutorial for Android Studio 1.0 in 2015

Tags: facebook, android-studio

I followed this [tutorial](http://trinitytuts.com/integrating-facebook-sdk-application-android-studio/)

but when its time for sync it says that in build.gradle(Project:test) the term apply plugin: 'com.android.library' its not found.. and that android-library is depreciated..

My question is there any tutorial which works? and when we say import facebook sdk we mean import it as module?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-add-facebook-login-to-your-android-app--cms-23837) is the best tutorial I saw after encountering the same problem you had:

If you have issues getting your key hash from the command line you can just get it from the code. Check AnhSirk Dasarp answer here: [Facebook Android Generate Keyhash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash/13488560#13488560)

Even with this tutorial you may still have some compatibility issues (perhaps not). Android studio is very good in resolving these issues, let him.

And yes, import Facebook SDK means import it as a module:
<kbd>File->New->Import Module..</kbd>