# Facebook unity login wrong hash?

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

So I've got everything setup for the facebook login on unity. 
I've got the hash provided on the facebook developer site / unity facebook settings( like this: 2jmxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxwk= ), but when I try to log in on my android phone it always gives the error:

> Invalid key hash. The key Hash KtWxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1l= does not
>   match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at
>   http://developers.facebook.com/apps/[appID]

Even when I fill in the hash provided in the error above, it gives the same error all over again. I checked the app ID I'm using and the hashes. If anyone has an awnser that'll be great because I'm trying to get it work for 2 days now.

Comment: A simple search yielded me this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12405323/2245773

Comment: Thanks man ! First deleting the debug.keystore , rebuilding it with eclipse, and then following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12405323/2245773) worked like a charm!