# ionic facebook login working locally but not in android app

Tags: android, facebook, ionic-framework

Ionic login is working locally and at [haz.heroku.com](http://haz.heroku.com)

However, when i run $ ionic run android and test app in android mobile, facebook login is not working. You can check my codes [here](https://github.com/asimkh/apps/tree/haz

[image: facebook app details]

For Android, facebook setting are updated as below. Once app is installed and click on Facebook login button, no error, message, nor login message prompts.

[image]

check this error details.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On Android, there is no localhost anymore. You have to add the Android platform instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add you Google Play package name and create hash keys and add them to your Facebook application.

1. Download openssl from the link bellow: https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list
2. Unzip it to a local drive (e.g., C:\openssl)
3. To get the Development key for facebook integration, use the following command from the command line in windows:

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe" base64

NOTE!: please replace the path for openssl.exe (in this example it is "C:\openssl\bin\openssl.exe") with your own installation path.

It will prompt for password, e.g.,
Enter keystore password: android
Type android as password as shown above.

Thats it! You will be given a 28 character long key.

Use the same procedure to get the Release key. Just replace the command with the following and use your release key alias.

keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | "PATH FOR openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | openssl base64

Credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32211444/4440845

The package name can be found in the config.xml file in your project.
For more information check out this tutorial : http://excellencenodejsblog.com/cordova-ionic-facebook-login-mobile-app/

Comment: i done the android setting and hash key but remain same issue.

Comment: how to debug on android?

Comment: You can try running your app using 'ionic run android' and then in chrome browser go to 'chrome://inspect/#devices'. You can see logs in the console.

Comment: Could I use the same hash key for both firebase and facebook, I have generated one as mentioned in firebase , and converted it to base 64 from a service on the internet, is that correct @Vandervidi?