# OpenSSL stops working when trying to decode base64 string

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to get the key hash of my Android app to get my Facebook login to work. I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12405323/5426939) as my tutorial.

Everything seems to go perfectly fine, until step 13:

> Again copy following code and paste
>
> openssl base64 -in debug_sha.txt > debug_base64.txt

[image]

I have the following files in my c:\OpenSSL\bin folder.

[image]

The debug.txt shows the following string:

> 0‚Ý0‚F0
>      *†H†÷
>    0710U
>   Android Debug10U
>   Android10    UUS0
>   170222090740Z
>   470215090740Z0710U
>   Android Debug10U
>   Android10    UUS0Ÿ0
>      *†H†÷
>     0‰ „¡½ÀŸ—'eÈë™‚*×º~5NŒ8^ö­yÐê¾„/6ú»Ð*{:œªËAà-Ènƒ-ó-<´9oTaJë'vpºYG£ÜRÌKoÒ`–J§4ÛÏß\ïv<¹ã°R‘ªŽóŸ^Ušéè¯øà9"y]Ä(l—Ó 0
>      *†H†÷
>     sN’÷žûD
>   Ì~Ä•´ôU?º:h8º<øçÝ†i«5:9È¶þÌ,ŒÝ1ÓµÄPœ1î#Õµp*y¤‰;¬O¬D¤cÝ¼û†W¿â*øöòR˜¬®ê3Û¦^-M5}&½¶¤³“ýFí¾DQ>>ˆùh+~ô1-·"¬ðí%€

The debug_sha.txt file shows the following string:

> aÈÈ¹µA=+‰GJƒ ªõå

the debug_base64.txt file is empty, but it did get created by the commandprompt.