# Ionic 3 - App gets frozen when running --prod mode in Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

When I run the app on device in debug mode everything works fine, but when I build with --prod and try to run it gets frozen and never goes after the splash screen.

I think that might be something related to Facebook, my app has Facebook Login.

There are lots of error in logcat but I cannot post here because is too much text.

```
01-14 16:11:49.014 5251-5251/? E/WebContentsProviderReceiver: onReceive - not approved application

    --------- beginning of system
01-14 16:11:49.484 855-1058/? E/MARsDBManager: updateDBAll : begin --size 3
01-14 16:11:49.554 855-1058/? E/MARsDBManager: updateDBAll : end
01-14 16:11:49.674 6891-6891/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.appmanager.nekodirect
01-14 16:11:50.214 5312-5312/? E/Zygote: v2
01-14 16:11:50.224 5312-5312/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
01-14 16:11:50.714 5329-5329/? E/Zygote: v2
01-14 16:11:50.724 5329-5329/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
01-14 16:11:52.354 5385-5385/? E/Zygote: v2
01-14 16:11:52.364 5385-5385/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
01-14 16:11:52.694 5385-5400/? E/SPPClientService: ShipBuild Binary : True
01-14 16:11:52.954 5329-5376/? E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID '181349075940707' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}
01-14 16:11:54.154 5312-5422/? E/HealthAnalytics: [HAnalytics] checkMandatoryProperty(), property ordinal : 1 is mandatory, but key is empty.
01-14 16:11:54.154 5312-5422/? E/HealthAnalytics: [HAnalytics] checkMandatoryProperty(), property ordinal : 2 is mandatory, but key is empty.
01-14 16:11:54.154 5312-5422/? E/HealthAnalytics: [HAnalytics] checkMandatoryProperty(), property ordinal : 3 is mandatory, but key is empty.
01-14 16:11:54.154 5312-5422/? E/HealthAnalytics: [HAnalytics] checkMandatoryProperty(), property ordinal : 4 is mandatory, but key is empty.
01-14 16:11:54.154 5312-5422/? E/HealthAnalytics: [HAnalytics] checkMandatoryProperty(), property ordinal : 5 is mandatory, but key is empty.
01-14 16:11:54.154 5312-5422/? E/HealthAnalytics: [HAnalytics] checkMandatoryProperty(), property ordinal : 6 is mandatory, but key is empty.
01-14 16:11:54.154 5312-5422/? E/HealthAnalytics: [HAnalytics] checkMandatoryProperty(), property ordinal : 7 is mandatory, but key is empty.
01-14 16:11:54.234 5329-5412/? E/File: fail readDirectory() errno=2
    fail readDirectory() errno=2
01-14 16:11:54.244 5329-5412/? E/File: fail readDirectory() errno=2
```

And here is my project config:

```
± % ionic info                                                                                                                                                                !10

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.5
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    ios-deploy        : 2.0.0
    ios-sim           : 6.0.0
    Node              : v8.11.3
    npm               : 5.6.0
    OS                : macOS
    Xcode             : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61
```

Plugins:

```
± % cordova plugin list                                                                                                                                                       !11
com.googlemaps.ios 2.7.0 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
com.telerik.plugins.nativepagetransitions 0.6.5 "Native Page Transitions"
cordova-plugin-add-swift-support 1.7.2 "AddSwiftSupport"
cordova-plugin-android-permissions 1.0.0 "Permissions"
cordova-plugin-camera 4.0.3 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.1.0 "Console"
cordova-plugin-contacts 3.0.1 "Contacts"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-email-composer 0.8.15 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 3.1.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.11.0 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.3.2 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-linkedin 1.2.1 "LinkedIn"
cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 2.3.6 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
cordova-plugin-media 5.0.2 "Media"
cordova-plugin-nativeaudio 3.0.9 "Cordova Native Audio"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 3.1.2 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-streaming-media 2.2.0 "StreamingMedia"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.1 "SocialSharing"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.5.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.0.0 "BarcodeScanner"
phonegap-plugin-push 2.1.2 "PushPlugin"
twitter-connect-plugin 0.6.0 "Twitter Connect"
```

Any word to help me solve this issue?

**Edit 1:**

```
01-15 13:25:28.461 27227-27227/jungery.bizcards.com E/Zygote: v2
01-15 13:25:28.471 27227-27227/jungery.bizcards.com E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
01-15 13:25:28.671 20699-26051/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error -4 during AudioRecord native read
01-15 13:25:28.721 13572-13572/? E/audio_hw_primary: stop_voice_note_recording
01-15 13:25:28.721 13572-13572/? E/audio_hw_primary: adev_close_input_stream, set jack_in to null
01-15 13:25:29.581 27227-27283/jungery.bizcards.com E/libEGL: validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
01-15 13:25:29.881 27227-27300/jungery.bizcards.com E/File: fail readDirectory() errno=2
01-15 13:25:37.551 27371-27371/? E/Zygote: v2
01-15 13:25:37.561 27371-27371/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
01-15 13:25:43.751 27371-27431/? E/GmsUtils: Failed to connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
01-15 13:25:55.091 855-1675/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 3530 [01-15 13:25:55.101]
01-15 13:26:09.811 26204-26204/? E/MTPRx: started activity for popup
01-15 13:26:09.931 27227-27227/jungery.bizcards.com E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
01-15 13:26:09.991 26204-26204/? E/MTPUSBConnection: AlertDialog Mode is : TIMEOUT
01-15 13:26:12.321 335-410/? E/DataRouter: USB Interface is open with 0xa
01-15 13:26:12.321 26204-26309/? E/MTPRx: state from USB_STATE event DISCONNECTED
01-15 13:26:12.331 26204-26309/? E/MTPRx: stop observing and calling usbRemoved 
01-15 13:26:12.331 26204-26309/? E/MTPRx:  sendbooster is false!
    In usbRemoved Status bar enabled
01-15 13:26:12.341 26204-26204/? E/MTPRx: Read Error Came false
    Read Error Came so calling usbRemoved()
01-15 13:26:12.341 26204-26204/? E/MTPRx:  sendbooster is false!
    In usbRemoved Status bar enabled
01-15 13:26:12.351 26204-26309/? E/MtpMediaDBManager: updateMyfilesDB Count :0
01-15 13:26:12.361 26204-26309/? E/MTPRx: Sending Broadcast finish
01-15 13:26:12.371 26204-26204/? E/MtpMediaDBManager: updateMyfilesDB Count :0
01-15 13:26:12.421 26204-26204/? E/MTPRx: Sending Broadcast finish
01-15 13:26:12.441 26204-26204/? E/MtpService: onDestroy.
01-15 13:26:12.461 26204-26204/? E/MtpService: Unregister Mtp disable Receiver
    Receiver not registered: com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$1@bb3a597
    Unregister mtpEmergencyReceiver
    Receiver not registered: com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$2@1bbb384
    unregistering mtpUserPresentReceiver in UnregisterAllIntent
    Receiver not registered: com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$4@f789816
    unregistering mtpMediaReceiver in UnregisterAllIntent
    Receiver not registered: com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$3@68dd931
01-15 13:26:12.461 26204-26204/? E/MTPJNIInterface: noti = 3
01-15 13:26:12.531 855-1306/? E/InputDispatcher: channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-15 13:26:12.921 27522-27522/? E/Zygote: v2
01-15 13:26:12.921 27522-27522/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
01-15 13:26:12.981 27522-27522/? E/MTPRx: In MtpReceiverandroid.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE
01-15 13:26:12.991 27522-27522/? E/MTPRx: check value of boot_completed is1
01-15 13:26:13.011 27522-27522/? E/MTPRx: Sd-Card path/storage/94AB-108D
    Status for mount/Unmount :mounted
    SDcard is  available
01-15 13:26:13.011 27522-27522/? E/File: fail readDirectory() errno=2
01-15 13:26:13.011 27522-27522/? E/File: fail readDirectory() errno=2
01-15 13:26:13.011 27522-27522/? E/MTPRx: check booting is completed_sys.boot_completed
01-15 13:26:13.011 27522-27522/? E/MTPRx: Sd-Card path/storage/94AB-108D
01-15 13:26:13.021 27522-27522/? E/MTPRx: Status for mount/Unmount :mounted
    SDcard is  available
01-15 13:26:13.021 27522-27522/? E/MTPRx: Received USB_STATE with sdCardLaunch = 0
    mFirstTime: false
01-15 13:26:13.051 27522-27522/? E/MTPJNIInterface: Getting CryptionKey from JAVA
01-15 13:26:13.061 27522-27522/? E/MTPRx: currentUserId is 0
    mtpCurrentGlobalUserId is 0
    Start observing USB_STATE_MATCH 
    usbMode is 0210
01-15 13:26:13.071 855-2261/? E/ENGMODE: Failed to enable UD-Mode(lecagy)
    Failed to open token (-1)
    Failed to read token(-12)
    the req mode is not allowed (-12)
01-15 13:26:13.081 27522-27522/? E/MTPJNIInterface: noti = 12
01-15 13:26:13.081 27522-27522/? E/MTPRx: is_Privatemode is NOT 1
01-15 13:26:13.121 27522-27522/? E/MTPRx: Sending NORMAL_BOOT to stack
01-15 13:26:13.121 27522-27522/? E/MTPJNIInterface: noti = 17
01-15 13:26:13.131 27522-27522/? E/MTPRx: User is personal
    sending MTP_ICON_ENABLED to stack
    else part ... so first time!!!
01-15 13:26:13.131 27522-27522/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr: inside setContext()
     inside createplafiles
01-15 13:26:13.141 27522-27522/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr: playlist count is0
     inside try branch createplafiles
     inside deleteing plas createplafiles
01-15 13:26:13.151 27522-27522/? E/MTPPlaObsrvr: Inside registerContentObserver
01-15 13:26:13.151 27522-27522/? E/MtpAdbObserver: inside setContext()
    Inside registerContentObserver
01-15 13:26:13.151 27522-27522/? E/MtpService: onCreate.
    < MTP > Registering BroadCast receiver :::::
    Calling registerBroadCastuserPresentRec() 
    < MTP > Registering BroadCast receiver for USER Present:::::
01-15 13:26:13.161 27522-27522/? E/MtpService: < MTP > Registering BroadCast registerBroadCastPolicyRec :::::
    < MTP > Registering BroadCast registerBroadCastEmergencyRec :::::
    onStartCommand.
01-15 13:26:13.171 27522-27522/? E/MTPJNIInterface: < MTP > Registering BroadCast receiver :::::
    < MTP > Registering BroadCast receiver :::::::
    noti = 10
01-15 13:26:13.171 27522-27541/? E/MtpService: handleMessage. msg= { when=0 what=0 arg1=1 obj=Intent { cmp=com.samsung.android.MtpApplication/.MtpService } target=com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$ServiceHandler }
01-15 13:26:13.171 27522-27522/? E/MTPRx: Checking the driver time out
01-15 13:26:13.171 27522-27522/? E/MTPJNIInterface: noti = 2
    event handler thread is created, so set the flag
01-15 13:26:13.171 27522-27522/? E/MTPRx: called native method
01-15 13:26:13.171 27522-27522/? E/MTPJNIInterface: setting Media scanner status0
    After setting Media scanner status0
01-15 13:26:13.171 27522-27522/? E/MtpService: onStartCommand.
01-15 13:26:13.171 27522-27544/? E/MTPJNIInterface: Getting media scanner status0
    DeviceName is Satan
01-15 13:26:13.201 27522-27541/? E/MtpService: handleMessage. msg= { when=-13ms what=0 arg1=2 obj=Intent { cmp=com.samsung.android.MtpApplication/.MtpService } target=com.samsung.android.MtpApplication.MtpService$ServiceHandler }
01-15 13:26:13.221 3261-3261/? E/MtpServerJNI: could not open MTP driver, errno: 2
01-15 13:26:13.221 3261-3261/? E/MtpServerJNI: server is null in add_storage
01-15 13:26:13.221 3261-3261/? E/MtpServerJNI: server is null in add_storage
01-15 13:26:13.231 3261-3261/? E/MtpServerJNI: server is null in send_object_removed
01-15 13:26:13.231 3261-27547/? E/MtpServerJNI: server is null in run
    server is null in cleanup
01-15 13:26:13.421 27522-27544/? E/MTPJNIInterface: Status for mount/Unmount :mounted
    SDcard is  available
01-15 13:26:13.531 27522-27544/? E/MTPJNIInterface: Status for mount/Unmount :unknown
    SDcard is not available
    Status for mount/Unmount :unknown
    SDcard is not available
    Status for mount/Unmount :unknown
    SDcard is not available
01-15 13:26:13.551 27522-27544/? E/MTPJNIInterface: Status for mount/Unmount :mounted
    SDcard is  available
01-15 13:26:13.551 27522-27544/? E/SQLiteLog: (21) API call with NULL database connection pointer
    (21) misuse at line 107734 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
    (21) API call with NULL database connection pointer
    (21) misuse at line 102845 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
    (21) API call with NULL database connection pointer
    (21) misuse at line 102845 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
    (21) API call with NULL database connection pointer
    (21) misuse at line 107734 of [2ef4f3a5b1]
01-15 13:26:14.141 27522-27522/? E/MTPJNIInterface: In MTPJNIINterface onReceive:android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED
01-15 13:26:15.151 27522-27522/? E/MTPJNIInterface: In MTPJNIINterface onReceive:android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED
01-15 13:26:20.301 27583-27583/? E/Zygote: v2
01-15 13:26:20.301 27583-27583/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
01-15 13:26:20.421 27583-27583/? E/SmartFaceServiceStarter: onCreate
    onStartCommand
    Starting SmartFaceService.
01-15 13:26:20.441 27583-27583/? E/SmartFaceService: SmartFaceService constructor for user: 0
01-15 13:26:20.511 27583-27583/? E/SmartFaceService: mActiveServiceType: 100
    mScrollEnabled:false mPauseEnabled:false mStayEnabled:true mRotationEnabled:false, (false,true)
01-15 13:26:20.511 27583-27583/? E/Logger: New Logger Instance
01-15 13:26:20.511 27583-27583/? E/SmartFaceService: mLightIntensityEnough: true mLux: 0.0
01-15 13:26:20.511 27583-27583/? E/SmartFaceService: Service Type to Worker: 0
    Last Active clients:0 Current Active clients: 0
    Last Smart Pause clients: 0 Current Smart Pause clients: 0
01-15 13:26:20.531 27583-27583/? E/SmartFaceService: from registerCoverManager -> mClearCoverOpened: true
    SmartFaceService constructor done
01-15 13:26:20.531 27583-27595/? E/SmartFaceService: Update service state according to cover state: true
01-15 13:26:20.531 27583-27583/? E/SmartFaceServiceStarter: onStartCommand done
01-15 13:26:20.531 27583-27595/? E/SmartFaceService: mActiveServiceType: 100
    mLightIntensityEnough: true mLux: 0.0
01-15 13:26:20.531 27583-27595/? E/SmartFaceService: Service Type to Worker: 0
    Last Active clients:0 Current Active clients: 0
    Last Smart Pause clients: 0 Current Smart Pause clients: 0
01-15 13:26:20.531 27583-27583/? E/SmartFaceService: SmartFaceService Started.
01-15 13:26:22.511 855-1809/? E/Sensors: Pressure old sensor_state 8705, new sensor_state : 8737 en : 1
01-15 13:26:22.551 855-2261/? E/Sensors: Pressure old sensor_state 8737, new sensor_state : 8705 en : 0
01-15 13:26:25.091 855-1675/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 3531 [01-15 13:26:25.103]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try below things.**

- Check whether you are connected to the internet.
- Check whether your app has permission for internet access.(AndroidManifest.xml)
- Check whether did you provide the correct [haskey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash/13488560#13488560) for the app.(In facebook Integration)
- Check whether did you provide a correct Facebook app id
- Check whether is your app live in facebook developer portal.

Comment: I checked everything you pointed, tried to run again and still no success, I also put the Production certificate HASH on Facebook Developer Portal. Please see my "Edit 1" to view the logcat output.