# How to Implement Facebook sign in using Firebase Flutter?

Tags: facebook, firebase, flutter, dart

i'm trying to Implement Google,facebook and email sign-in in my project, i have completed google sign in,now im trying to work on facebook.so i started with registering through Facebook developer portal and was following the steps which it showed me but i'm stuck in the 4th step which is this:

[image]

I tired running that command in my terminal but it displays like this:

[image]

I have java installed in Computer but i don't know what's the other two requirements for running that command,can someone tell me how can i fix this.

Comment: Please do not show screenshots of text and code on Stack Overflow.  Copy the text into the question so it's easier to read and search.

Comment: Sorry sir should i add the link of the website then?

Comment: You can do that too.  But the question should contain everything needed in the question itself.  Don't rely on external links, which could become stale over time.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to be the error is you are using **USERNAME** in the command

replace that **USERNAME** with your pc username

for using hashkey for facebook

follow my answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54513168/9236994