# Problem with generating key - Android

Tags: android, facebook, keystore

I'm trying to get the key hesh from my app for integration with Facebook.
I've followed the Signing your Application guide on the Android Developers(http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#setup), and the Android Facebook guide(http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android).

My problem is that I don't know how to properly get the key hesh from the keystore.
Here's what I do in the cmd -

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore  C:\Users\Mickael.android\debug.keystore

Then it asks for a password, and then shows me a very long gibberish key.
Now I know that key is encrypted. The facebook guide offers 2 commands -

| openssl sha1 -binary

| openssl base64

But I don't know how to get them to work.

Here is a picture of the problem -
http://img543.imageshack.us/i/keyfail.jpg/

I could really use some help

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: use [THIS][1] tool to generate a key.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388992/key-hash-for-android-facebook-app/17732453#17732453

Answer (score 0):

The output you are showing isn't going through the base64 encoder.  Make sure you do the entire line below in a *single line*.  The post makes it look like new lines, but they all need to be run as a single command.

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore 
| openssl sha1 -binary
| openssl base64

Answer (score 0):

See:

[Key hash for Facebook Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347924/key-hash-for-facebook-android-sdk)

Comment: Ok thanks,both answers helped me. Now i'm stuck with the openSSL. I downloaded the libraries from the link you gave me, but how can get it to work?

Comment: Never used it myself, but I think I'd just put the two dlls and the .exe in a new folder and add that folder to my path