# Android: Error when login Facebook using new Facebook SDK v3.0.2.b sample

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

when I using new Facebook SDK v3.0.2.b sample HelloFacebookSample, I login to Facebook but I get error:

> HelloFBSample is misconfigured for Facebook login.

But I have already generate Hash key and add it to Sample App Setting on Facebook Developer site.

Is anybody get the same defect?
Or is it a bug of new SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the Key Hash generated using the method given by the Facebook Doc does not always work as advertised. I have faced this problem and so have a few others.

There are a couple of things you can do to sort it out.

**First method**

Follow the tutorial on this site: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1

This is a little time consuming (about 5 odd minutes I expect) but worked when I tried it.

**Second Method** (And I personally like this one)

1. Find the `Util.java` in the Facebook SDK and open it.
2. Among the first few lines of code, you should see this piece: `private static boolean ENABLE_LOG = false;`.
3. Change the `false` to `true` and run your application with your logcat (DDMD) open.
4. You should see an error that looks something like this:

> Login failed: invalid_key:Android key mismatch. Your key
>   "******real*key*********" does not match the allowed keys specified in
>   your application settings.

If this is for a testing APK, using the **debug.keystore**, this will be enough. However, if this is for an app signed with your release key, then follow the steps till Step No. 3 but instead of pushing the app from eclipse, create a signed APK and install that on your device. Don't forget to keep it connected with DDMS running.

This part here: "******real*key*********" is your **actual** key.

Comment: Thank bro for your feedback.
Finally I have re-generate the Hash Key and the App run OK.
It's maybe the error from keytool ^^

Comment: I obtained the correct key from the **First Method**. For the **Second Method**, the key (between the double quotes in the message of `com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException`) is missing an _equal sign_ at the end. Since it is [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding), it should end with 0, 1, or 2 _equal signs_. I am using Windows, `facebook-android-sdk-3.0`, `keytool` is `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin\keytool.exe`, `openssl` is downloaded from [here](http://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/) (from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4348379/1402846)).