# Key hash not being generated

Tags: java, android, facebook, keytool, android-keystore

I was trying to get the key hash from my Android app. Facebook SDK 3.0 gave the following code:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

When I run this it first says `binary:no error`; It then asks for the password which I enter as `android`. Upon pressing enter it returns blank where I expect the pass code.

I used the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347924/key-hash-for-facebook-android-sdk); this did give me a key hash but when I use that none of the sessions are opening.

My java keytool is stored in :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin
```

And OpenSSL is stored in :

```
F:\openssl\bin
```

I am giving the correct file paths when I run it in MD in Windows.

Kindly help me figure this out!

Comment: Also another one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might got the password wrong.

Look at my answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17732453/2476453).

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Windows is always a little hairy and tricky to get the keytool, I suggest the alternative.  Run the following code in the `onCreate` method of your app:

```
   try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "COM.YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME", 
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("My Keyhash", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("My Keyhash", e.toString());
    }
```

and observe the log output in logcat to obtain your keyhash.  Make sure to replace the package name above with your own.

EDIT:

> the key hash is correctly uploaded but the session still does not open... while logging on to facebook it first requests for my permission throgh the app and the after i accept a popup come up saying "com.facebook.facebookexception: Session Provided to a request in unopened state"

Make sure you have this code in your Fragment/Activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: thanks .. the key hash got generated but i updated my app but the session still dosen't work.

Comment: you're going to have to provide more detail than that if you want help (e.g. stack trace, error messages)

Comment: the key hash is correctly uploaded but the session still does not open... while logging on to facebook it first requests for my permission throgh the app and the after i accept a popup come up saying "com.facebook.facebookexception: Session Provided to a request in unopened state"

Comment: yes a version of that code is present... the issue is that even sample apps given in the facebook 3.0 SDk are not working and give the above error

Comment: I would try removing the app from your authorized apps in your FB settings and then re-authing the app.  Apart from that, it sounds like there is a configuration issue with your app because I have not heard reports of the sample apps having this problem and I am unable to repro either.

Comment: i am also getting the same above issue,how to reslove please help?