# facebook cocos2d-x integration invalid key hash

Tags: facebook, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I followed [How to create Android Facebook Key Hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506392/how-to-create-android-facebook-key-hash) `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` and the result matches what is on my facebook app settings page I still got the same error

Answer (score 1):

I was trying it recently. And I used android platform.

I found there are two key hashes I have to find out.

1. The key hash at my build environment saved at /.android/ like you did.
2. The key hash from the device, which mentioned in this link( the reply of "you can use code below to get the Hash key" ).
   [Key hash for Facebook Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347924/key-hash-for-facebook-android-sdk)

I filled them both at facebook app setting. I hope this helps you.