# Can't post on facebook with signed APK

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

just started using Facebook SDK for android.

I'm creating an app to post images on facebook, I am using the facebook 4.6.0 version.

I can post Images with the debug version of the app (but I can only post with the administrator account of the facebook app, don't know if that's normal or not). After the creation of the signed APK I can't post with any account on facebook don't know why.

I think my Key hashes are correct...

I am using this method to get the release key hash:

```
private void generateHash() {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.teracoding.screenquotes",
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
}
```

I also tried generate the key from the terminal with this command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias “mealhas” -keystore “path to .jks" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

but still nothing ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you published your app? I mean turn on the facebook app?

Answer (score 0):

I am also suffer this problem, you have to generate **KeyHash** from your generated **keystore** than update Facebook developer page with new **keyHash**, becasuse your local keyhash is not supported, 
Plz refer this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347924/key-hash-for-facebook-android-sdk)

Comment: How can I do that in Mac OS?

Comment: yes, I already tried to generate the hash key with the terminal, I updated my post with what I did but still nothing works I don't know why ...

Comment: Have you try to review your app on facebook?

Comment: @MohitSuthar no I haven't .. Do i need to do the review to all users be able to use it? How do I review my app?

Comment: You can go threw the facebook developer page and than submit app review for your app