# facebook keyhash issue one mobile run app but other device does not work?

Tags: android, fbloginview

when I develop android app that time debug mode my app facebook login working very well but when i create release app and install other devices then error for different key hash error

Comment: i think, you have to create new key hash using your keystore, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347924/key-hash-for-facebook-android-sdk

Comment: u have to generate key with released key store and add it to the facebook developer console

Comment: U need to create hashkey with your release keystore and update facebook app console with it

Comment: does not work provide batter solution